# Found an account that was created with the obvious intention of spamming only, what to do?

Tags: support, spam

After flagging [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509273) (now deleted) q&a that was obviously asked & answered by one and the same entity with the intent of advertising their service, I happened to view the account profile of [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6396751/bing-coupon) spammers, that has since (1h) been heavily extended:

> Bing Coupon Founder & CEO at **redacted to avoid pushing this company**
>
> **redacted to avoid pushing this company** is offering Bing Coupon for new ad accounts of Bing.
>   Bing is one of the best advertising platform for business.
>
> You can promote your business on Bing and can get a lot of business
>   with Bing Ads.Advertising on Bing and Yahoo ad network you can do
>   together.
>
> Advertising on Bing and Yahoo Ad networks is cheaper than Google
>   Adwords.
>
> We have latest and working Bing Voucher which can save your money.
>
> Below are the conditions to use this coupon :-
>
> 1-It works in new ad accounts only or less than 30 days old accounts
>   of bing. 2-You can use one coupon per account. 3-Coupon works
>   worldwide in any country billing. 4-You can use within 90 days of
>   redeeming voucher. 5-Coupon value is 107$ 6-Price of coupon is $10
>
> FOR MORE DETAILS CALL US at **redacted to avoid pushing this company** / **redacted to avoid pushing this company** Skype id
>   **redacted to avoid pushing this company** Email **redacted to avoid pushing this company**@speakmeme.com
>
> You can buy online at **redacted to avoid pushing this company** we accept paypal, skrill,
>   bitcoin, neteller, perfectmoney as payment method.
>
> if you are from India then you can pay us via netbanking or cash
>   deposit or cheque deposit also.

Now, I think it's pretty obvious that this account will only be used for spam, even if that has only happened once this far.

What to do about such accounts?

Comment: I don't think there is much more to do, honestly. They've already been tainted by a spam flag, so the moderation team has its collective set of eyes on them (especially if they persist and more spam flags come afterwards). "Stalking" the spammer in order to flag their further posts ASAP just looks like a waste of your life. You did the right thing, move along :)

Comment: Anybody can create an account, as many as they want, using any unreputable email provider without anything like 2-step verification.  And use them to *instantly* post a question.  A feature that's also heavily used to create sock accounts to upvote your own posts and to bypass question bans.  Deleting such an account is pretty pointless, they'll instantly create a new one.  SE is just not interested in doing anything about it, it is the hard work of SO users like you to keep the abuse in check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posts you mentioned were detected by the [Smoke Detector](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/29656) and reported in the [SOCVR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psOJ8.png).

Both posts got spam flags but the question got the SPAM flag that caused the Q/A to be deleted. That means the asker account is now at a -100 rep penalty.

Some moderators go over the SPAM reports and might destroy accounts. If the accounts happen to be able to post again, they will be reported by Smokey once more and a second bunch of spam flags is enough to get them silenced. Account removal will happen after long enough incapability to post.

Beyond flagging there is not much more needed. We're pretty effective with deleting SPAM. You could flag one of your one posts and link to the SPAM profile explaining that the profile only exists for SPAM. Do know that their needs to be evidence of spam posts in that case. Advertising in your about me is allowed.

Comment: Any idea where I get some more information on smoke detector?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid sure, [here is the wiki](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki) and you can see it in action in our room, for example [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32404435#32404435)