# Should Stack Overflow be more restrictive about new user registrations?

Tags: discussion, new-users, accounts

The largest problem facing the site today is the flood of terrible questions coming in, mostly from new user accounts. I've [mentioned this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256258/would-asking-a-question-at-a-reputation-cost-help-improve-quality-durability-f/256277#256277), but I suspect that some of the worst of this is due to people who have created multiple throwaway accounts to evade question bans and other limits. Others create fake sock puppet accounts to vote for themselves, and the vast majority of voting fraud seems to take place in order to circumvent question bans and other quality safeguards.

In recent discussions, [there have been comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324015/found-an-account-that-was-created-with-the-obvious-intention-of-spamming-only-w#comment349512_324015) that it's time for Stack Overflow to be more restrictive towards new user accounts. At first, you didn't even have to register to post a question, but [complaints about hit-and-run askers led to a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163). I think it might be worth exploring what could be done next, if anything.

I strongly believe that placing a reputation requirement on asking a first question would be a disaster for the site, for reasons [I describe here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253168/low-rep-users-should-not-be-able-to-ask-questions/253179#253179). People would spam non-answers and trash until they could game their way into posting a question, and vote fraud would run rampant. You think the 100+ non-answers a day we see now due to the 50-rep comment threshold are bad? Wait until you can't ask questions below some rep threshold.

So Stack Overflow needs to make it possible for a legitimate new user to ask a question without any previous posts on the site. With that as a restriction, how can "legitimate" accounts be determined?

An obvious first step would be to prevent the use of throwaway email providers for new accounts. In my experience, there's a very high correlation between people using sharklasers.com, mailinator.com, yopmail.com, etc. addresses and bad behavior (question-ban evasion, trolling, and sock puppetry). That seems like low-hanging fruit.

However, that's only a small fraction of the fake accounts I encounter. Almost all of them are created using Gmail or other legitimate mail hosts, often even using the mail host of the company the puppet operators work for. Moderators commonly trace people based on patterns of how they create email addresses, but these patterns don't seem easy for a machine to pick out. There are the obvious cases (an account using puppetoperator1@gmail.com voting for an account using puppetoperator2@gmail.com), but again those might only be obvious to a human looking at them.

The [recent locking of accounts deleted as trolls or spammers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/automatically-suspend-accounts-recreated-after-a-moderator-deleted-the-original/278803#278803) has really helped to prevent re-use of credentials. I still think that should be expanded to accounts deleted as sock puppets, but it at least blocks common cases of credential re-use.

IP-based restrictions are already used, but they're tricky to get right. Many, many public-facing IP addresses have dozens to hundreds of Stack Overflow users associated with them. That makes it difficult to associate a new fake account with the existing original, even if they are on the same IP. However, I have started tagging question-ban evasion accounts as trolls when deleting them in order to block near-future posts from that location. It has been effective at stopping more persistent ban evaders, but I worry about people getting hit in the crossfire with that. There might be a way to leverage more intelligence here.

Requiring some kind of two-factor authentication for new user signups has been suggested, but is this something that would work across the world? Would it be effective at slowing the creation of these new accounts? What form would this take?

I don't have any great solutions for this, and it's a topic that has come up recently, so I thought I'd start a discussion about this. Do you think there should be additional restrictions on the creation of new accounts, and if so, what should they be?

For now, I'm asking here due to the unique challenges faced by this site and because I can only speak to my own experience as a moderator here. I also figure that Stack Overflow has a number of people with experience in this area that might be able to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: Maybe the only thing that could be done is _throttling_. Don't a allow new users to ask questions within their 1st week after registration or so. Encourage them to search and research, and also just watching out on how the site works. These users should have visited a minimum number of Q&A pairs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The problem is that most people (I think) create an account just to ask a particular question

Comment: @SleimanJneidi One could _maybe_ argue that if a question isn't worth coming back to and asking in a week it probably isn't a great question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I understood that well. But being quarantined for a certain time will make this option far less attractive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and that assumes the person showed up on Stack Overflow as soon as they had a problem.  How do we know they haven't done weeks of research first, then signed up to ask a question.  Not quite as bad as a minimum rep limit, but seems very unfair to users who have legitimate questions.

Comment: @DonkeyKong:  That implication may not hold.  I don't quite have the time to run some queries, but I'm willing to bet that there are a decent number of questions asked by new users with a positive score.  It's likely not a *lot* but  I also wonder how that number skews if they've actually posted a question a week later.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - That seems like it would cause frustration among good new users and would only delay the "do my work for me" folks. The latter would learn to create a bunch of accounts and stagger their use after they had aged. I've seen spammers do this to circumvent IP blocks on new accounts, where they create several accounts and then activate each once the account is old enough to pass the block threshold.

Comment: @Makoto Oh for sure, yeah, I don't really believe it myself - Occasionally I see an awesome question from a 1-rep user and it's a really uplifting experience :) just throwing the thought out there.

Comment: Maybe a new queue or make the new questions visible only to >X rep users to vet it first. The registration can stay the same, but first X questions need to be approved.

Comment: Borrowing from @πάνταῥεῖ throttling idea.  What about more aggressive rare limiting for brand new accounts.  It still has some of the same issues Brad just mentioned in the comments, but would allow for asking questions but at a much more controlled rate.  Perhaps even provide even more guidance when trying to ask additional questions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  Queues aren't the best method for this since you're relying on those who frequent the queues to always get the vetting right.  They're having enough trouble with the triage queue as it stands...

Comment: @Makoto Seeing all the other comments above, doesn't look like _always right_ is achievable. I think _mostly right_ is desirable.

Comment: From my experience on SO with Java questions, most bad or off-topic questions are very similar. I suggest building a classifier that classifies questions from new comers, this might nag a reviewer or a moderator to review the question.

Comment: @BradLarson after rereading your question, I'm wondering if the comments are going off track - are you primarily looking to tackle the "Low Quality" problem or the "Multiple Account/Fraudulent Voting" problem.  I know they are related to some extent, but probably require different solutions

Comment: @psubsee2003 - There has been some work on tightening the throttle for new users who start out poorly: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/19679 . It used to take three or so questions to hit a limit, and I've seen this kick in after a single new question for some people lately. Of course, some of them go and create a new account for each question, which has been a joy to deal with. Thus this question.

Comment: Random idea: What if we would require a phone number for registration and you need to register your phone? I mean creating a new email address is fast and easy, but to get multiple phone numbers not. And I mean pretty much everyone has a phone these days.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm a student living in a foreign country and I don't have a phone :( maybe that or email along with some other additional identification form though.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - More on the question ban evasion / puppetry side of things. If we could trust the question ban to kick in early enough, and it became really hard to work around it by creating a new account, I suspect a chunk of the bad questions would be prevented before they were even asked. Sock puppetry is usually associated with someone evading a question ban, so making that harder would also play into this. Other aspects of question quality can be discussed separately.

Comment: What if new questions from new users started out closed, and would need to be reopened to be answered.  There'd be a new close reason just for it.

Comment: @Servy I would love that! That would even reduce the amount of moderation which needs to be done to close a new question.

Comment: @Servy Who can vote? >X reputation? Tag badge holders?

Comment: You cannot reopen something that was never opened before;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Perhaps new users could be somehow forced to read the list of related questions before allowing them to post their question. It might be shoddy because you can't actually force people to read things (EULAs still go unread), but perhaps there is something that can be done to direct new users more forcefully towards them.

Comment: @Servy I think this might deserve more thought, it's an interesting concept. It might work better to allow a new question to be (re)opened by fewer than 5 people, but still require a decent amount of rep in the tag. I like it.

Comment: @Servy:  Notwithstanding the point that it sends a very negative message to potentially positive contributing users, it implies that there are enough people around in whatever tag(s) they used to reopen the question, or that there are enough people to objectively reopen the question.  Not a lot of questions get reopened around here with respect to the number that are closed.

Comment: @Makoto A change like this would place reopening in a different light, making it more common. Also, it might work to only enable it in high-volume tags, which could be objectively determined. (Android could definitely benefit from this, and has the users to pull it off)

Comment: @WilliamKappler Well not such wasn't proposed before [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process).

Comment: @Servy As mentioned, _**quarantine**_. them. That sounds like a very good idea.

Comment: @Servy - That (if implemented) could be a different problem. Imagine being a person who posts a very good question after doing a lot of research but has to **wait for someone to say that its OK to be on the site**. *The number of people looking at the queue could be quite less* and that could make the OP wait for a *lot of time*. We should not make the innocent suffer to prevent morons from trolling / spamming.

Comment: @TheLostMind We'll review the question either way, won't we? If it's worth to come up, it'll come up at least. The time it needs to be answered doesn't really play a role, since we're looking for the _long term_ quality anyways.

Comment: @TheLostMind What if we still allow answers, but they are blocked and not shown until the question gets reopened?

Comment: @makoto questions are rarely reopened because they rarely merit it.  People don't actually fix closed questions.  If this were implemented many would merit opening, so the stats would change.

Comment: @Undo:  Fair point, but this still doesn't satisfy my other concerns; namely, there is the scenario which TheLostMind brought up, and also, the negative message still persists.  Although in fairness, I don't think much could be done about that.

Comment: @thelostmind I didn't say hide it until it's approved, I said close it.  People would see it, they just couldn't answer it.  Great questions would get more than enough attention to get opened.

Comment: @Servy I really like your idea. The comments here don't do it justice, would you mind writing up a meta question for it?

Comment: @Servy:  I'm still playing Devil's Advocate here.  What if there are good questions buried in the deluge of closed questions?  Would fatigue take over and result in good questions going missed here?  Also, what of the stigma that a question being closed carries, although implicitly?  I'm not getting any assurance that the questions would get looked at after being closed, is all.

Comment: @Tunaki Brad is looking at this more from a 'preventing duplicate accounts' point of view (to combat abuse); while Servy's suggestion is more about hobbling crap questions (to combat low quality).

Comment: @TheLostMind Quarantining new posts is common on other platforms. Often times first posts need to be approved before they are visible. The suggestion here sounds very similar, with the bonus that instead of a small handful of moderators, we have a large community of users that can assist.

Comment: @Andy - It could be a feasible option on other sites. This approach of quarantining would enrage new users (who would probably leave SO and never return back). Also note that, *correcting a post is a continuous process*. You reject it once, Bingo, it pops there again. You reject it again, Bingo!, its there again.

Comment: As far as sock-puppet voting is concerned: What if you could only vote on a question by a new user if your account was older than **x** with reputation greater than **y**? That would require sock puppets to have the sock puppet account for awhile, and it would have already have had to gain some reputation on its own. Apply the same to answers regardless of account age.

Comment: @crush - This would fail in most cases. For those evading question bans, their main account might have been around a year and have 200+ points of reputation. They create a new account, use it to ask questions, and vote for it from their blocked main account. This can prevent the new account from being banned, no matter how many bad questions it asks. The new account can also then vote for the main once it passes the 15 point threshold, potentially lifting the ban on the main account. Age and rep level on the main account aren't good filters, and would have tons of false positives.

Comment: @BradLarson Why is the blocked account allowed to vote?

Comment: I'm not sure, but since there are hardly a lack of people willing to become moderators, this seems like a bit of unnecessary muscle flexing.

Comment: @undo I've seen the idea a few times before, so it's not brand new.  Not sure if I could actually find a question for it though.  As for it not being about account creation, I did say it would be for new accounts, so it is in effect adding a "cost" to making a new account.

Comment: Regarding the two factor suggestion: [That was declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256767/186281)

Comment: I would vote for @Servy proposal to be trialed on a few tags, chosen at random, C, Android, PHP and jQuery, say.

Comment: I think what we have to consider is that more and more commercial companies outsource their support to SO. For instance google (Google Project Tango) have no official support site (neither a forum, email or ticketing system). It's only one example. A lot of others (especially providers of web APIs, frameworks and so on follow this trend more and more). People who need and expect support, because it's the only way, should be able to register and post. In my opinion the punishment for deliberately violations should be harder and more consequent.

Comment: @martin you forgot regex.

Comment: @dannyyy SO isn't obligated to support those products.  If those product owners feel SO doesn't provide the support their customers need/want, then it's on them to provide more.  SO isn't a support site after all.

Comment: Something like the idea Servy proposed was put forward quite a while ago. [Require a net +1 for questions in high volume tags to become answerable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108822) See also: [Should questions by new users have to be approved before becoming generally visible?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185530) Neither of these, unfortunately, were very popular at time of posting. (Actually, I'm pretty sure Servy has proposed this before, but it may have just been in a comment then too.)

Comment: Not a fan of preventing questions for a week.  I could see where new users don't actually create an account until they have exhausted their researching efforts and are ready to finally ask a question.  I believe needing to ask a question is the single most driving factor to new account creation.  No one is going to create an account and then wait a week.

Comment: The problem is not the poor ones trying to ask question, the problem is not the poor ones trying to answer a question, the problem is the great ones that do not put any effort in to moderation of the community, setting some standards for the poor ones... close the bad questions please stop answering them all you great ones and tell us poor to do the same... no answer to poor questions == no poor questions, no puppet accounts,  *and then if some great one close a question wrongly stop all the meta blaming him (discussing close reason), just edit the question and vote to reopen*

Comment: @Kevin  '.....exhausted their researching efforts and are ready to finally ask a question' yes indeed.  The problem is the other 99.9% of new accounts.  The current 'accept all the crap because 0.1% of questions don't totally suck' is not sustainable.

Comment: Also, what @PetterFriberg says.  It's very easy indeed to find hopelessly-trivial and multi-dupes questions, probably from puppets and/or rings, with half a dozen upvoted answers, often from 20k+ rep-personalServicesWorkers :(

Comment: Regarding mailinator.com:  Banning addresses from there may sound like low-hanging fruit, but that site has umpteen alias domains.  It would actually be a lot of effort to discover their full list and ban all those domains.

Comment: @dannyyy Read [Why we're not customer support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: I'm glad to see you asking this, maybe the time is coming where SO sets a stance for not giving instant answers, but being more no nonsense in what we tolerate. If carefully planned there must be a way to circumvent this trend.

Comment: @Brian: Huh? http://www.google.com/search?q=mailinator%20alias%20list -> https://gist.github.com/nocturnalgeek/1b8fa44283314544c487

Comment: @TheLostMind it depends on the rules. Let's base it on privileges: 1. if 3 users with 100+ rep say it looks fine but requires to be edited it's unlocked 2. one 10k+ user can unlock it right away 3. only two votes from 1k+ users can relock it. All users effectively become gate keepers.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, I think Careers was possibly better when registration was limited to invite-only. I'm not saying make SO invite-only, but perhaps having this be an option to skip any new user restrictions might be nice.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's a start :)  OTOH, mailinator boasts "hundreds" of alternate domains.  The list in your github link only contains 24...it's a bigger task than "Add mailinator.com to a ban list"

Comment: @Brian Agreed. Spammers and sock-puppets will use whatever they can until it doesn't work, then find something else just like it. So, while mailinator might be popular today, if it gets banned (even all of its hundreds of domains), another will just spring up to takes its place tomorrow.

Comment: @Brian - In reality, I rarely see any of the mailinator alias domains, it's almost always the main site. Maybe if it was blocked people would switch to the others, but maybe not. When the common URL shorteners were blocked, I didn't see a sudden switch to the less common ones. People pretty much stopped using shortened links. Blocking the main mailinator domain also makes it a little harder to compromise these accounts, which has happened on multiple occasions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277999/135615

Comment: Perhaps this question should be featured for a while? It's a pretty fundamental change to the site that deserves some time in the spotlight.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's actually how I joined Stack Overflow. I, for one, hated having millions of accounts on random sites, so I didn't want to get an account here at first. I still used it frequently, finding questions and answers before having had an account. I signed up for an account once I wanted to ask a question - but I was a "user" for weeks before that.

Comment: Make SO invite-only?

Comment: Instead of starting new user questions as closed, what if they went into the First Posts review queue and remained invisible to the site (except to the poster) until approved? The poster would see the question as if things were normal, yet the rest of the site wouldn't display the question until approved in the queue. Maybe alter that queue a bit so that senior SO members could easily approve the question while otherwise requiring X votes from those under the threshold. A badge could be created to incentivize the use of the queue.

Comment: @Makoto: [This graph](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312370/number-of-new-accounts-that-have-their-first-question-closed-shortly-after-accou/312374#312374) (plotting the fraction of first questions that are closed vs. account age) might be relevant. Basically, it seems that there is indeed a noticeable effect, but a) it's quite non-linear, b) it mostly plateaus off after one hour, and c) in any case, it turns out that most new SO users ask their first question less than an hour after creating an account; most of the variation presumably comes from the time it takes them to type it in.

Comment: Far too late to the party, but I would honestly recommend reading this proposal I wrote more than a year ago which rather than with arbitrary restrictions attempts to address this issue through more focused and thoughtful UI: [Give greater dominance/placement to searching rather than asking for new/low rep users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/give-greater-dominance-placement-to-searching-rather-than-asking-for-new-low-rep)

Comment: One naïve question. Would it not be possible to reduce the First Posts Review Queue threshold to 500 rep or even to 300 rep? A user with that many reps already knows what is a good and a bad question. This would easy the moderation requirement for higher rep users. The same could be done for the Close vote Queue for reason of low quality or spam, like 500 reps (specifically for the filtering of obviously low quality questions). Just an idea.

Comment: StackOverflow is a good website for helping each others no ? What about this idea: If a new user is registered, he must have at least 30 rep (or any numbers ##) for asking question ? We want users to help each others I believe that will makes their integration to StackOverflow easier and will stay instead of "Question and Left" the community. @DavidMulder your link is a really good read, everyone should read it.

Comment: @ib11 I second that idea, it would be good to give some basic moderation privileges as you've mentioned. Also, flags can be raised against spammers to make sure content is not vague.

Comment: Nope. How about less restrictive?

Comment: related idea http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279934/can-we-implement-the-low-quality-flags-to-delete-posts-after-a-certain-number-of

Comment: Just thinking about IP blocking, what about browser fingerprint blocking? Evercookie, etc.

Comment: I've heard something about throttling here. I don't think that's an good idea. I don't think you should restrict functions to new users, because then the whole helping fly's away. The site is here to help users with their questions, when they're forced to search, and they can't find an answer, they will leave the site, with the impression that the site can't help them.

You can request that they search first, but you shouldn't deny any permissions when it's about asking a Question. Users come to stackoverflow for help, not for more hopelessness. Everyone was new here. Don't feel better.

Comment: @PascalBoschma I think throttling is a great idea. It will keep away people who registers just to get a quick answer. If they cannot understand that throttling is a tool to make the site better, then they will probably not contribute either.

Comment: Whatever the mix of solutions include, it needs to be easily added to. The number of `rep=1` questions asked -- and then later deleted, has reached a fevered pitch (which usually surrounds the months of May and December that correspond to the close of the semester). The sock puppet issues has seen a large spike in May as well (at least for C, C++ tags). There are many comments of seasoned users openly questioning "Who upvoted this question" (or answer). One automatically helpful tool would be a prevent-delete by users with less than `100` rep. That should discourage some.

Answer (score 138):

I feel like we need some numbers to help understand the problem here. I'm not going to draw any conclusions, just present some data that's a bit hard to get... If you think of something else that'd be useful here, let me know.

I grabbed some numbers from questions posted between 60 and 90 days ago (to avoid temporary "settling" problems). These numbers include questions that were deleted, and to the extent possible, those that belonged to deleted *users* as well - so spam and sockpuppets aren't neglected. For this 30-day period,

- **276,792** questions were posted, of which
- **24.62%** have a positive score,
- **19.52%** have a negative score,
- **32.87%** are answered,
- **12.06%** are closed,
- **20.27%** are deleted,
- **24.22%** are closed *or* have a negative score,
- **14.5%** are answered and have a positive score,
- **3.36%** are answered and have a negative score

Now, for the same 30 days, I found that:

- **51,199** questions were asked by users who had never posted a question before, of which
- **20.85%** have a positive score,
- **31.81%** have a negative score,
- **20.68%** are answered,
- **19.66%** are closed,
- **29.17%** are deleted,
- **37.37%** are closed *or* have a negative score,
- **9.14%** are answered and have a positive score,
- **3.57%** are answered and have a negative score

And to complete the picture, I looked at questions during this time period from all users who *hadn't yet earned the [remove new user restrictions privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)* (10 rep) when asked:

- **108,664** questions were asked by "new" (unprivileged) users, of which
- **20.04%** have a positive score,
- **28.55%** have a negative score,
- **21.78%** are answered,
- **17.57%** are closed,
- **26.79%** are deleted,
- **33.92%** are closed *or* have a negative score,
- **9.4%** are answered and have a positive score,
- **3.54%** are answered and have a negative score

### Requests:

**Brad asks how many new users eventually hit one of the quality bans.**  4.74% of users who asked their first question during the time period above later encountered a quality-block of some form based on their past questions. More may have qualified but never tried to ask again.

**Brad asks how many new users had a quality ban hit from their IP *shortly before* asking the first question,** (a potential indicator of someone trying to circumvent the ban).  Looking back a week from the time the first question was posted, **1,999** users posted from IPs that'd previously had someone hitting a ban. Looking back a day sees this drop to **1490** users.

**Makoto asks if patience is a virtue in folks asking questions**, wondering if the age of the account at the time the first question is asked makes a significant difference. To do this, I have to ignore posts from deleted users (since I've no way of knowing when they were created), which is fine because doing that exposed a bug in the query I used to do that anyway (I've corrected the numbers). It turns out destroyed accounts only account for a couple % of posts, so with that out of the way, let's look at *first questions* from patient users (for the same time period as above):

- **14,690** questions were posted by users who had never posted a question before, BUT who had created their accounts at least a week prior to asking, of which:
- **24.35%** have a positive score,
- **25.62%** have a negative score,
- **22.30%** are answered,
- **16.24%** are closed,
- **24.60%** are deleted,
- **30.86%** are closed *or* have a negative score,
- **11.07%** are answered and have a positive score,
- **2.56%** are answered and have a negative score

Comment: For the purposes of this question, do you have the percentage of new users during that timeframe who hit the question ban? Also, this might be more difficult to extract, but do you have the number of accounts created at the same IP that another account recently hit the question ban at (with "recently" possibly being maybe 24 hours, 48 hours, a week apart)? Not saying all those accounts are bad, just trying to put an upper limit on the recidivism problem.

Comment: Is that, "new users who hit the ban in that timeframe", or "new users within that timeframe who hit the ban then *or at some point later on*", @Brad?

Comment: Analogous to what you've got here, would you consider including a correlation between [account creation time and overall net score](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations#comment350803_324220), with divisions based on a weekly basis?

Comment: @Shog9 - Probably the latter, indicating the percentage of the above new users who got picked up by the system. That might not be as relevant to this question, since I'm trying to find an upper limit on the number of accounts that could have been created to work around question bans. The new accounts wouldn't necessarily be the banned ones (although you could imagine they might follow the same path as the previous account).

Comment: Also, could there be a breakdown in percentage by positive scored questions with an answer versus negatively scored questions with an answer?  I've got another hunch I'd like to verify.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the % open but with at least one close vote in these numbers?

Comment: I just worked that last one into the existing tables, @Makoto.

Comment: Aren't the deleted stats kinda skewed by the 30-day roomba? (since a downvoted question with no answers would automatically be deleted)

Comment: @hichris123:  I believe Shog queried 90 days worth of data to reduce the noise from that event.

Comment: @hichris123 Shog has acess to the internal SEDE that can also query deleted posts, I assume he did consider this.

Comment: Not significantly different from "closed or downvoted", @Travis; I just added that since it's a heck of a lot easier to explain.

Comment: That's why I picked a 30-day period 60 days in the past, @hichris123. Note that this also avoids skew from the recent changes we made to quality-banning and rate limits.

Comment: Now that you provided all these, can you write up your conclusions, too (different answer)?

Comment: So basically users without the 10-rep privilege are worse in every category, and the overall data with regards to 276,792 questions asked *includes* their rates. Without it, the group of 168,128 questions would probably stand out even more as outperforming in every category.

Comment: That's kind of a self-fulfilling thing though, @Travis: that group includes everyone who has *never* managed to get an appreciable number of upvotes on anything they've written; the folks who do move out of it. The best conclusion you can draw from it is probably that past performance doesn't indicate future results.

Comment: Do you track how much time users spend writing up their questions?

Comment: My conclusion at this point is... "insufficient data for meaningful answer", @SotiriosDelimanolis. Everyone sucks at asking questions; folks who've been around a while do a little bit better, so encouraging people to read must be a priority... But it's not a panacea. Questions are still sand, and there's an awful lot of sand that never becomes a pearl.

Comment: Only as part of a spam test, @Braiam; the result is discarded.

Comment: In the deleted column, what percent of those were already closed prior to deletion?

Comment: Darn, that would actually be interesting, ie. is there a relation between the time you spend writing your Q and the result (up/downvotes, closed, answered)...

Comment: About 8% for the whole set, @TravisJ.

Comment: Can you also give a rough estimation about how many questions are involved in voting fraud? It seems to mere that there are two separate issues here. Is this question about tackling voting fraud or addressing the flood of low quality posts?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324233/3956566 I've asked a question **Can we determine if there is a minimum rep point where this percentage drops significantly?**

Comment: 20% Positive Score by [New Users] . Isn't it sufficient to answer the question?

Comment: As I will write my question in MS-Word (for spell checking), then may google a bit more, before hitting the "ask question" button, is it meaningful to consider how long someone spend on the ask question page?

Comment: Looking at a tag like PHP, 90% of the up-voted questions would not have been up-voted in the "good old days".     Without running stats on thinks like "up-voted by a tag badge holder", I can't see a way to separate the worthwhile questions, and the questions that are upvoted for no good reason.

Comment: What are the stats like for "question has had a least one down vote" for each group of users?  Also number of downvotes per 100 views may be an indicator.

Comment: Can we have the stats for:  “users with more than {50, 250, 500} rep at time of asking”,  “users with a bronze badge in at least one of the questions tags at time of asking”,  “users with up voted answers in a least one of the questions tags at time of asking”.

Comment: I wonder if these stats differ significantly between tags. For example php, Java, C#. Or maybe the distinction between high volume tags vs low volume?

Comment: I believe your post would gain in clarity if you removed one or two digits from the percentage figures.

Comment: Request: Can you put these in a table? It's hard to compare the numbers by scrolling back and forth.

Comment: @Claudiu How's this? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ZH1js2MsFyGW0w081udezKi9BVNY4veEC3f9JvBt0w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Shog9: I think it would be interesting to look at the crap rate for accounts who posted at least one answer before their first question?  And then break that down by "real" answer -- got upvoted vs "used the answer box to work around comment restrictions" -- answer is deleted.

Comment: @DavidG: Perfect! Now I can easily see the clear trend, for example, between 1st time posters & 1st time posters who waited a week, the latter being higher-quality. Whether forcing them to wait a week will result in this is a matter of what the causality is.

Comment: @DavidG much clearer to read as a table, thanks. Any chance of adding a bar chart to see this visually?

Comment: @brichins You should get some automatic barcharts if you click explore on the bottom right. If they're not right, I'll add some in.

Comment: @DavidG very nice - didn't know that was available. Been a long time since I've used Sheets. A few of the points it brings out are interesting; if I have time after work I might make a copy of the sheet and try to come up with other graphics that might be useful & post or message them to you. I'm a very visual thinker... which sounds better than "now say that slower and with pictures." :)

Comment: Could probably use privilege level for that, @BenVoigt. Won't get to it today, but I'll see what I can throw together next week.

Comment: Could you run these statistics for users who earned the Informed badge before posting their first question?

Comment: In my experience, question up-votes are extremely rare -- and correlate strongly with the usefulness of the question, but not the quality.  For a new user, this can be a rather harsh experience (I would imagine).  I wouldn't use up vote counts to judge the quality of questions.

Comment: One problem with these statistics is that many (IMO) shite posts get upvoted by similarly shite users

Answer (score 128):

If you want to reach new askers, "ask" yourself this:

**Why hasn't the /ask page meaningfully changed since 2010?**

Here's a screenshot of the ask page circa 2009 from the wayback machine, next to what it looks like right now today in 2016.

[image: SO ask page, 2009 vs 2016]

I'd argue that the ask page is the one page on Stack Overflow that has changed the least in the last 5 years. Given the increasing volume of questions, and the [importance of question quality to the whole Q&A ecosystem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) — that's … strange.

If you want to reach new askers, you need a better /ask page. A whole lot better. How can this page interactively teach new users how to ask better, and raise the bar for the quality of the questions being asked?

Comment: "interactively teach new users"... I still think the best way to to that is by showing example questions from a curated list that shows good and bad examples, and explains *why* they are good or bad. Perhaps even based on what is currently being entered.

Comment: Not enough freehand circles showing the differences.... we are still doing that, right?

Comment: @Gnoupi: Isn't that the point?

Comment: @BoltClock: well there are some differences still... but mostly I haven't been on meta for a while and attempt to rehash old memes.

Comment: The only thing I've noticed about the /ask page is that it gives me possible duplicates to the question I want to ask. I sometimes use this because I don't find what I'm looking for in a site search. Other than that there is nothing that really "helps" a new user ask better questions. I think Jeff is on to something here.

Comment: Fundamentally I agree with this, but my question would be, how would a change like this actively resonate?  There are people who will seek to do write better questions and will do their due diligence when writing a question; there are people who will always consistently ignore any message we put forward to try to convince them that they should pay attention to the matter.  If the bulk of the problem is the latter group, no amount of change to the Ask page is going to make a difference since they will always insist on ignoring it.

Comment: it is a game of statistics. At Stack Overflow scale, even a 5% improvement in question quality from a better guided /ask page would be huge. Given the 2010 era design of the /ask page I humbly suggest we could do at least that much better?

Comment: For example, instead of the related search coming up (belatedly) in the sidebar, it could be the next thing you see after submitting: with a "Are you sure you still need to ask this question?".

Comment: Absolutely! We've been saying this at Programmers for a while... the time to catch a user's attention is when they choose to get invested in the site by asking a question. There should be something big and in your face to say *"Wait! We have rules for posting questions, be sure you are familiar with them before asking!"*. It doesn't have to be long or interactive, just something that grabs their attention and tells them what they need to know before asking.

Comment: I'd love to see some A/B testing with variants of the *ask* page. We have the perfect metrics to follow through on question quality too.

Comment: It may also be that you want different ask pages for different users. A much more hands-on, guided ask page for new users and a stripped-down, to-the-point ask page for users who've asked many questions that have been positively rated. (Or any number of variations in between.)

Comment: [status-bydesign] :-)

Comment: I like the idea of improving the UI. A year and a half ago I asked what effect barriers would have on new users. The best answer (imo) was one which suggested rephrasing the approach as "what sort of barrier could we impose that would have the smallest negative impact with the greatest positive impact?" and went on to suggest that an improved UI for asking would satisfy that. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274814/1026459 Even if we managed to have new users properly understand tagging/titling their questions with an improved UI it could reach your statistical low hanging fruit number.

Comment: Jeff, you of all people should know that here at SO, we don't post questions as answers to a question... :)

Comment: @Rusty Not the case with Meta :)

Comment: I _could_ agree if I saw a single thing that could be improved (well, I do, but they are minor). The page pretty much does what it's designed to do - allow to ask, ingrain and enforce basic rules for asking (tags titles), try to make it unnecessary. It could summarise the gist of asking better (maybe style: direct and to the point, no disclaimers, evidence>opinions). It could enforce it better (disclaimers, more kinds of useless titles, tag in title)...

Comment: ...Other than that - the search is pretty much all the local eggheads are capable of now, I guess. The submitting interface is pretty standard - maybe, showing tag wikis/tag usage guidance somewhat more prominently would help (there's been a lot of complaining that tag wikis are invisible).

Comment: Here's one of my suggestions for "interactively teaching new users": http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: and based on the comment by @Pekka웃 , this suggestion aims to show new users what is expected of them with examples, much like reviewers have review audits: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly

Answer (score 70):

It's difficult to prevent users from creating throw away accounts. The obvious email providers as you mentioned can be banned, but then this leaves the trash that is posted from accounts such as gmail.

This makes me think that this suggestion [Can first posts be reviewed before being becoming visible on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308481/can-first-posts-be-reviewed-before-being-becoming-visible-on-the-site) might be the way to go, having a lower rep requirement to review such posts. An example of 500. Although this would slow down post becoming visible on the site, it would prevent garbage also being visible on the site. If this garbage never becomes visible to the general public or lower rep users, then there will be less joy for such users to create throw away accounts, as their questions will never find answers.

It would be interesting to see the stats on such a change on the efforts of spammers and trolls, as if they cannot view their public handywork, it may slow down their efforts, again it may not.

I think it would be worth a temporary trial to test such a system and see if the community can cope with the review queue.

Account registration for answers could also be enforced.

---

[Looking at the stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324244/3956566) [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) has posted:

Total deleted, closed or negative score questions of users < 10 rep:

> 33.92+26.79% = 60.71
>   60.71 * 108664 = 66091

Total deleted, closed or negative score of all questions:

> 24.22 + 20.27 = 44.49 
>   276792 * 44.49 = 123145

Total deleted, closed or negative score of all questions of users > 10 rep:

> 123145 - 66091 = 57053

20.61% of all questions asked by users greater than 10 rep are deleted, closed or downvoted.

***Can we determine if there is a minimum rep point where this percentage drops significantly?***

Reviewing posts of users < 10 rep before making them visible would significantly reduce close and delete review queues, as posts that are not made visible would not need to be vetted.

Comment: I am not convinced it would prevent garbage, given the quality of some of the users with 500 rep!

Comment: I would love that post starts closed or need to be reviewed the only big problem I see is with the low-traffic tags, currently it is impossibile to close a questions in these tags (excluding posting cv-pls request), probably with review que on questions in the end it would be impossibile to ask.

Comment: @IanRingrose in some ways true, but many people take pride in their accounts and rep and new privileges attained. So it may work. It would slow down questions being visible, but then the site would gain a rep of being more no nonsense and people would soon get used to that.

Comment: @PetterFriberg yes the review rep would need to be carefully considered and tested.

Comment: I like this, I wouldn't mind getting a review - as long as I get feedback if something is amiss

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you're saying here. Aren't you basically talking about Triage + H&I (but somehow preventing people from seeing the question until its been triaged)?

Comment: @hichris123 that first posts are not visible on the site until reviewed. The exact tweaking of how much rep users need to have to review that queue and how many positive or negative reivews are needed for a post to be visible would need to be thrashed out. But it prevents new accounts posting directly to the site. It creates more work. So the question is, Is it worth it? It could well raise the standard of the site. And the name of the queue or whether we use an existing queue would need to be worked out. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Also, imagine if we didn't need to close or delete questions that do not become visible? That would reduce two queues.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the triage queue that is already in place.

Comment: I think there is a lot to be said for the long-term effect this stance would take. Namely that users who have been just posting trash, spam, or other non-sense would likely give up since it wouldn't make it out of the review queue to hit their target audience.

Comment: Temporary hiding garbage and forcing other trusted users to review all the garbage is not a scalable solution. It is only going to end up like the close vote review queue full of old questions filled with crap waiting for someone to review and delete them. Make for number verification mandatory. If they are question banned, they are question banned. They must improve the crap they posted to get rid of it, or register new mobile numbers every time they get banned and eventually end up in some agencies possible terrorist list for having so many mobile numbers ;)

Comment: I hope you noticed my Inception pun, I also wanted to add that I've heard that in some countries having more than `n` number of mobile number registered on your name is a blocker for getting stuff like visa... Mobile number verification is the way to go.

Comment: @TJ there would be more reviewers due to lower rep to review and there'd need to be less reviews to cast a question visible or for editing

Comment: @Yvette Yes, there will be more reviewers, but I think there will much more questions in that as well than the ones getting a close votes from those who has the privilege and time which ends up in close votes queue. So the outcome is likely to be the same. Also there is a chance that these 500 rep reviewers are likely to go to the crap questions and answer them for reputation. So there should be other mechanisms like locking the question than just controlling visibility in main page. I'm in favor of preventing garbage than hiding garbage.

Comment: I ask consistently crappy questions on SO, so if I refrain from asking, that will help :D

Comment: @TJ yes I've wondered about people reviewing and then answering. Maybe there could be a 24 hours embargo on answering if you review it as ok?

Comment: Don't users already have to be registered to answer a question?

Comment: @Yvette: there's actually a badge for editing and answering within 12 hours; I don't see reviewing and answering as different and in low bandwidth tags you would be delaying answers for little reason...

Comment: @TylerH not they don't, they only need to register to ask.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes true. There's certainly no easy solution.

Comment: @Yvette your standard of crappy questions is poor.   You should spend more time on Android and PHP to improve your crappiness.

Comment: I like the review idea for new questions, I think the threshold for review should be raised to 1K reputation.

Comment: @Yvette Wow... that's horrifying

Comment: I proposed a Pending Questions Queue over on this meta [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316635) . If the timeout is 0, flush to main, well that is what you have now. An argument against it is "who would man it?" . Well we all are manning it now, it is just that the questions never get a clearance and they go Live.

Comment: @Drew yes I upvoted that answer. It was a very divided vote. It solves the problem of a huge queue.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think people were wildly in favor of having their peers determine if their question was ready for prime time yet (including spam). Sense of entitlement I guess.

Answer (score 33):

You pose two separate issues here.

One in your title which is "Should SO be more restrictive with new user account creation?" I think that the current amount of work done on the Stack Overflow team side has been great. The email banning process seems complicated and that is also an issue with the use of the OpenID system in general. I am not sure there is much more that can be done here.

---

The other is about barriers to asking questions. I am fairly familiar with these discussions on question quality and restrictions. These are some of the questions I have asked trying to address this topic:

- [What effect would introducing a small barrier for new users to ask a question have on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252061/1026459)
- [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/178816)
- [Make it easier to close job shop "gimme teh codez" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308837/1026459)
- [Offer redemption to confused question banned users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211135/178816)
- [No one likes quitting cold turkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230857/178816)
- [New users don't value reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269120/178816)

I agree that reputation should not be used as a line in the sand barrier. However, that doesn't mean it should be outright ignored.

**I propose a rebalancing of barriers towards asking questions through the combined metric of reputation and close votes.**

This would essentially be deputizing users to have a stronger impact on new users. It could start small.

- Introduce an additional two close reasons which are only applicable and only available on questions asked by users who have less than 6 reputation at the time of asking.
- Reduce the amount of total close votes required to close questions asked by users who have less than 6 reputation to 2.
- Allow users with gold or silver tag badges to close questions from 1 reputation users with 1 vote.

Comment: FWIW I know shog does not like complicating the close vote rules.

Comment: "Allow users with gold or silver tag badges to close questions from 1 reputation users with 1 vote", if only the "do my work" questions did not get up-voted and answered quicker then anyone can get to them.   But giving more closing powers to gold/silver badge holder would be of benefit.

Comment: @IanRingrose Fewer close vote requirements would give those users much less time to answer before it got closed, at least. So *fewer* of those questions would get answered.

Answer (score 26):

> ## Should Stack Overflow be more restrictive about new user registrations?

We seem to be shooting down most suggestions that intend to have the net effect of throttling new questions. I'm attempting to list the canonical suggestions and reasons they are being shot-down or at least the questions that are being raised.

The principle here is that given a random (genuinely) new user, we want to immediately accept their input.

This is an important principle. In short, it's a "No" to your main question.

But the problem the question is getting at is the problem of too many bad new questions, and an inability for Stack Overflow to handle them all.

### Principles

First, here I enumerate principles that are guiding this discussion:

1. Given a random (genuinely) new user, we want to immediately accept their input.
2. This site was created in part in response to the way [Experts-Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) behaved. It would be a departure in strategy and offend many pre-existing users if we act like they do.
3. Bad-faith users will do whatever they can to get around roadblocks for posting, so we have to align incentives so that they don't create problems in other areas.
4. "We don't want to spend a lot of effort developing something that might not work." I think this is probably a really bad principle, and investors in Stack Overflow would probably not be happy with it. You have to weight risk as a cost in making a decision on the capital expenditure.
5. Don't make the innocent suffer. I think this is fine unless it prioritizes new askers over answerers. Remember, *innocent* answerers are suffering from all the bad questions.
6. Given a bad question, if we can fix it (remove the badness) and answer it (not necessarily in that order) then we should.

### Other's Suggestions

So in the context of the principles, I'll address the suggestions:

- [Two-Factor Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication): Will young users or people in the developing world be able to authenticate? See principle 1 as well.
- Impose time delay between account creation and ability to ask a question: No - see principle 1.
- Test new accounts (programming or even IQ testing): See principle 1.
- Charging $1 to create an account: see principle 2. Also they would act even more entitled - they paid after all.
- Minimum reputation points to ask: See principles 1 and 3.
- Penalize answerers of bad questions: See principle 6 but also we can downvote such answerers if we think they are behaving egregiously.
- Question Wizard: I think this can be tuned so that it makes it *harder* to get around without violating principle 3. It violates principle 4, but I think that's a bad principle anyway.
- Review before going live on the front page: See principle 4, likely not an easy modification to the site. Also, this is a marginal violation of principle 1. However, this is approximately what [Hacker News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News) and [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) does with their "New" sections, their "front page" is essentially "Hot Network Questions", and I don't think they get a lot of complaints.

### Suggestions:

In light of the above analysis, here's my suggestions, in multiple parts:

#### Suggestion to Users

If you see a bad question, and you can fix and answer it, then do so. If it's bad and unfixable, and further, if you think an answerer was wrong to answer, you can downvote the answer as well. If you were right and it's all deleted, you regain your rep point you spent on the downvote anyways.

#### Suggestion to Stack Overflow

Let's explore 2 factor authentication as a way to accelerate the rate at which we trust new users. Multiple contact points may encourage better behavior because real world reputation would be more in minds of those who authenticate at a higher lever. However, I'm against making it mandatory for the present.

Give askers a better interface to guide them away from pitfalls and keeps them on-topic to the site.

Give answerers a better set of screens. Allow them to create their own ranking algorithms that can give different weights to recency and upvotes (within certain tunable parameters such that this is not a burden on the server-side). Thus answerers who want to see questions from new accounts can see them and those who want to limit their view to better questions could do so.

Comment: "This site was created in part in response to the way Experts-Exchange.com behaved. It would be a departure in strategy and offend many pre-existing users if we act like they do." - yes, this. The whole purpose of Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange) was *not* to be some annoying site that makes you jump through twenty hoops just to get an answer to your question. We cannot forget that original purpose.

Comment: I often forget that there are investors backing StackOverflow, and its not a community funded venture like Wikipedia, for example. The fact does impact the direction of the discussion.

Comment: This is a good overview of the suggestions for account creation restrictions and potential downsides of each. A centralized resource like this was part of what I was hoping to get out of this question.

Comment: Can you clarify principle 4? I'm having trouble parsing it. Do you think that it's a bad idea not to spend a lot of time on something that might not work? Or that our investors would be unhappy with us not spending time on something that might not work? There are a lot of negatives in those two sentences that I can't quite place in the right spots. Thanks!

Comment: @hichris123 That's not it at all.  The problem that the founders had with EE was that the useful information that the site created was kept hidden behind a paywall.  The problem was that the useful answers weren't accessible; the problem was not what it took for someone to be able to *ask* a question.

Comment: @Servy Considering in [Podcast #4](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W781), Jeff said, "As it stands now, we were hoping that guests could come in and add answers, add questions all they want without creating an account.  This is another way we're different from some of the other sites where they really force you to create a login almost immediately.", I would assume that Jeff & Joel wanted it to be easy to ask a question. (ironically that's no longer true, you do need to register to ask a question)

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, and that's in a radically different context, it was also when the site was very small and struggling to have enough content, rather than now, when the site is struggling because it has too much content.  My point stands, the core problem that they had with EE was hiding the useful answers, not that not everyone could ask the questions.

Comment: @hichris123 It's worth pointing out that Stack Overflow's scope, purpose, goal, etc. can change over time. There are a lot of ideas being thrown around on meta this week (it's been a busy week here!), and some are pretty great, but frankly none of them are going to gain much traction until the community first has the ability to sit down and have a frank discussion with (or read a frank expose from) the Stack Overflow company and what it views the site's purpose as today. For years now the community has pushed the site in a direction clearly different from its origin or its system.

Answer (score 24):

**Learning from the credit card fraud prevention industry**

I believe a possible solution (or improvement) to this situation should actually by learning from other service, sites that are facing similar problems.

Online credit card fraud prevention is an industry that is tasked with doing the exact same thing for e-commerce sites. Their goal is to find the users creating junk accounts with stolen credit cards and making a one time purchase on a specific site - sounds very similar to the situation being described here.

**Credit card fraud prevention**

Most solutions rely on two approaches: Databases of bad accounts/stolen credits cards and risk scoring.

In this case, I believe risk scoring can be used rather effectively to root out most bad questions, so I'll focus on that.

For credit cards, risk scoring will look at a number of factors and assign a value to each factor, and then combine them to give a specific transaction a risk score. If the total score is above a certain threshold, the transaction will be flagged or blocked.

**The Stack Overflow Risk Scoring**

Implementing a similar solution for Stack Overflow should not be too complicated. Some of the variables I can think of are:

1. Email domain, as some have mentioned some domains are at a higher risk than others. They should just get a higher score. Lets say +5 for gmail, but +15 for aol.com (etc.)
2. Length of question, very short questions, or very long questions can indicate an increase in risk.
3. Number of tags. If there's a connection between number of tags and bad questions, it can be added to the mix.
4. Specific tags - is the risk higher for specific tags?
5. Spell checking - very high percentage of spelling errors should increase risk score.
6. Visits on the site before asking a question. Did the user just type stackoverflow.com and post a question? Or did he visit the site a few times today?
7. How many searches did they do before asking a question?
8. How many questions and answers they looked at before asking a question.

I'm sure people with more knowledge of Stack Overflow can probably come up with even better factors that will make it much more effective, but what's important to note is that usually a single variable will not be enough to get the transaction above the risk threshold, lowering the risk of false-positives.

**OK, so we flagged a question, what now?**

There are two usual ways to deal with flagged transactions on E-commerce sites. One is the completely block them and one is to flag them for human review.

This site is perfect for the second option. If a question is above the risk threshold it will just need to be reviewed before it will be available to the public.

**Summary**

I believe this approach can significantly reduce the number of bad questions by new users, while limiting the impact on legitimate new users.

I'm truly humbled by the level of discussion here, but wanted to add my [two cents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun).

Comment: I believe [the Triage queue is currently doing exactly this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) ([the feature request for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users))

Answer (score 23):

## A different approach?

> I suspect that some of the worst of this is due to people who have created multiple throwaway accounts to evade question bans and other limits.

If that is the case, what if instead of trying to limit all accounts, we disincentivize doing this for the user. How you ask? For that, we need to address the reason why they are doing this.

#### They create new accounts because *it works*.

Users posting bad questions eventually get banned yes, but usually not before **they get *some* help**.

We see this all the time. In a really bad case, a user posts a bad question and does not get an answer, so they post it again, and again until they get lucky (often deleting the old ones to make it harder to track). Eventually they find someone willing to answer the question (sometimes a low-rep user, sometimes not).

There is a period of time for which a user *can* ask bad questions and *get answers* before they are banned.

#### But *why* does it work?

Because we incentivize people to answer them!

Weird huh?

Answering a bad question currently tends to reward the answer with upvotes and reputation points, even as we penalize the question with downvotes (sure some users downvote those answer, but still). The OP may lose some rep and get banned, but what do they care when a fresh new account can give them a clean slate to start again with? They got what they really came for anyway, an answer, not some internet points.

#### What if we hold ourselves to higher-standards, and *not* answer these questions?

If these users never got any help from us, would they keeping coming back? I doubt it. Spam bots don't care, but if a real person never gets answers, or at least has a really low success rate, they would probably move on (perhaps to harass some BB forum or something).

#### How do we get everyone on board with this?

There have been some discussion on this issue in the past.

- [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes)
- [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)
- [Rewarding overzealous users for answering duplicate questions is undermining the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the)

Sadly many users do not consider this issue or are not aware of it. Only a small percentage of users even contribute to Meta. Yet there are many people to vote on lame answers to common problems. It seems the low barrier to answering simple and repeat questions means there are even more people to upvote those lower-quality but technically correct answers than there are great answers on more complicated topics.

Comment: I've personally dealt with many question-ban evaders who never received a single answer on any of their questions, yet kept creating new accounts as each one was banned. These folks aren't looking around at questions of similar quality and seeing if they're answered, they see good questions with good answers sitting atop Google search results and think that means they can get an answer themselves. What stops many of these question-ban evaders isn't a lack of answers to their questions, it's us temporarily blocking their IP addresses and applying other throttling mechanisms.

Comment: @BradLarson Well, that's unfortunate. Is the majority like that? Do they ever give up without IP banning?

Comment: That's one of the things that I was trying to somehow extract from Shog9's statistics. From those, he states that 4.74% of new users in a 30-day period eventually hit the question ban. 1999 users during that period posted from IPs where someone had hit the question ban in the past. Assuming all of those were new posters, that's 3.9% of the total, and assuming all of those were question-ban evasion accounts, that's 82% of those banned in that period. Those assumptions are bad, but that seems like the maximum percentage of people who could be evading a question ban in this period.

Comment: My perception is skewed by anecdotal evidence, where I've seen lesser-trafficked tags be dominated in short periods by a single user creating 7-10 new accounts, one banned after another. The regulars tend to recognize this and shut down new questions pretty quickly before they get answers, but the user would keep coming until we did something more drastic. Talk to the [coldfusion] folks about the one guy who has inundated them from dozens of accounts. That guy has also dumped questions all over Quora and other sites in an attempt to get any of them answered.

Comment: @BradLarson I remember that flood, I was probably one of the first to notice it, and I don't even watch that tag. I tend to think they might have actually been trolling or something. Perhaps my perception is also skewed, hopefully we can get some more stats on this.

Comment: Unfortunately, most people who are still learning to write software don't interpret a lack of an answer as "your question is stupid", but as "nobody knows the answer", so they keep asking it a different way or on a different site.  Punishing users for answering their questions will, therefore, make the problem much worse.  And the rep requirements for "Vote to close" are too high.  It should be easy for **anyone** to flag a suspected dupe.  Otherwise, the only way for the rest of us to make that known is to answer the question, which you want to punish us for doing.  That solves nothing.

Comment: Let me correct that slightly.  You can also comment instead of answering.  Either way, in categories where few people help out, there's a decent chance that nobody with privileges will ever see the comment and flag it as a dupe, so the result is pretty much the same clutter.

Comment: @dgatwood I'm not sure I follow. You're saying we should just give them answers so they stop asking? Doesn't that send the wrong message?

Comment: Answer them, **but** the answers should explain clearly why their questions are bad so that they can learn from it and ask better questions.  We should help them figure out search terms that would answer their questions (e.g. with the currently banned LMGTFY) so that they learn how to construct good searches.  In other words, treat even bad questions as a teachable moment, even if it is just teaching them how to write better questions or avoid asking them.  And it should be easier for anyone to flag those questions as "Roomba should happen soon".

Comment: And if they don't learn from their mistakes and keep asking bad questions without searching, then bring down the banhammer with full vigor.  You could even measure the quality of the questions by the percentage of lmgtfy links relative to the number of questions asked or answered by that person.

Comment: @dgatwood I think it would be too inefficient to do that for every bad question. If they ignore the close reasons, they'll ignore the advice too.

Comment: You're assuming they get closed.  The problem is, most of them don't.  And if they do, it is too little, too late.  Most users don't have enough rep to flag something for closing, which means their only options are downvoting the bad questions.  Unfortunately, that's just a number, and provides no indication of why we think the question was bad—something that is often obvious only to people who are familiar with that particular narrow subject area, not to generic queue reviewers.  So our only real option is to answer and tell them why it's a bad question.

Comment: @dgatwood I agree too many bad questions go unclosed, but I don't think doing the thing closing is meant to prevent is the solution. There has been some discussion on making closing easier.

Comment: I would argue that this isn't what closing is meant to prevent.  From my perspective, closing is meant to prevent the questions from being clutter that everyone has to step around when choosing which questions to look at and answer.  An accepted answer does the same thing.  But yes, making closing easier (particularly for dupes) would be a good idea, too—specifically, removing or drastically lowering the rep threshold for voting to close.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm gonna have to disagree with you. For the case you mention in comments, it seems to me like the process is mostly *working*. They eventually get stopped. But *far, far* more often, I encounter poorly researched questions that get upvoted and someone answers before someone casts a second close vote. The first is often mine, and *very* often it's because the question wasn't really clear. But people make guesses about what the OP is saying, rather than getting them to clarify. Are the questions you're talking about downvoted and closed?

Answer (score 16):

## Account-Creation Restrictions

Blacklisting one-off email services like Mailinator is as far as we should go with account creation restrictions.  These services have a generally negative connotation: their users intend to sign up for something they know nothing about or even distrust, or are trying to accomplish something insidious (like ban-evasion).  I'll also add that, if a new user has that kind of fire-and-forget attitude about SO, it's a good time to educate them on *why* the address they chose isn't allowed.  Doesn't have to be long, just something to the effect of "We want you to stay around and help our community grow and cultivate the most righteous Q&A!  Please use your real email address."  Such sentiments will be lost on the ban-evaders and vote-gamers, but hey, users new and old should receive feedback for their actions.

## Question-Asking Restrictions

Below, I outline three common question-asking restrictions and my thoughts on them.  In general, I don't think the impacts of these kinds of restrictions would be positive enough to justify.

#### Minimum Rep

Forcing users to answer questions or edit posts before they can ask their possibly amazing question is a terrible idea.  I think the gamification and vote-fraud that this solution encourages would die down over time, but only because of how many innocent users it has turned away from the site in the process.  There have been other cases where a trial period has been implemented to gather data for the justification of a suggestion--I'd be curious if this suggestion has received such a trial period in the past, but I would personally hesitate to even try.

#### Minimum Age

We received some interesting data from [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324244/4206756) on this front.

```
                Account Age | < 1 wk | >= 1wk |
 % of first questions which | 37.37% | 30.86% |
 were closed or have a
 negative score
```

Before seeing Shog's data, I was originally against this idea.  I'm still on the fence: there may be some recoil related to forcing this behavior compared to the users who did this voluntarily, and I still worry that well-researched, burning questions would be lost forever during this trial period.  However, in the interest of sustainability, I think this could be one solution we at least try to gather more data for.

This approach differs from the previous rep requirement in that we're not demanding anything of the new users.

> Hey, take a look around!  We suggest that you take the time to learn
>   how the site works over the next week or so before you ask your first question.

feels a lot better than

> Hey, take a look around!  Please read this documentation about reputation and
>   how to get it; now go get to work!  If you don't give us something useful in
>   return for our services, we're never going to allow you to ask a
>   question here.

Leading into my alternatives, I think it's important that, if this suggestion is implemented, the idea that "You have lots of options to find a similar question to the one you want to ask right now" needs to be stressed during this "trial period".

#### Minimum "Approvals"

The idea here is to allow users to post any question freely, but remove its visibility from the site until a triage-like voting queue allows it to pass through. Another interesting idea with possible drawbacks -- let's get some data!  My initial reaction is to not go in this direction, as it is both misleading to users and potentially frustrating with minimal paths to feedback.  To take the sustainability perspective again, creating a second triage queue actually sounds pretty silly, but I admit I may be missing the point here.

## Alternatives

#### Incentivize dupe-finding

This section of my answer already has already been discussed in other answers to this question (and many others).

I think it's important to help curb the overflow of answers to bad questions by offering the gamifiers a more constructive path to their goal, as defined as better-aligned with the community's goals.  Namely, give rep for successfully identifying a duplicate.  We could even emphasize this in the how-to-answer section, explaining the ways to seek out dupes and why finding a duplicate question is better overall for the site than answering localized, no-effort questions before searching for existing resources.  This may encourage unnecessary dupe-voting, but I think the trade-off leans in a very positive direction for the site in terms of sustainability.

As a side thought, users with enough rep for a dupe-hammer shouldn't need this incentive at all, so we can safely assume that questions will only be accepted as dupe under reasonable circumstances.  This would assuage the gamifiers' inevitable attempts to gamify...  of course, it's also wishful thinking, so something like this deserves a data-collection period as well.

#### Search-first UI priority

> "Wait, what's a tag wiki?"
>
> -me reading a random meta thread nearly a year after joining SO.

There are many resources available on this site that are unfinished, unfindable, and/or unexplained for the uninitiated.  Sure, research can happen before a user makes it to SO, but we have to get it across early on that this isn't just a Q site.

Now I will concede that incremental learning is the natural progression of things, and that we cannot expect to make new users experts who have assimilated all opinions and culture from meta before they post their first question.  However, with the poor-quality question tsunami in mind, we could at least try modifying the UI to help users *find answers to their questions that already exist*.

Users in general tend to follow the "path of least resistance" to accomplish what they want. I think suggestions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/give-greater-dominance-placement-to-searching-rather-than-asking-for-new-low-rep) (which modify the path of least resistance from clicking ask, submitting, and waiting) are the least destructive way to encourage new users to use the resources available to them before posting a horrendously under-researched question.  We don't want to restrict users from asking their bad questions--instead, we should first help them see what other options are available first.

As an aside specific to tag wikis, I would add to the above suggestion by saying that tag wikis should be a #1 priority to show new users who haven't used them yet.  Not all users randomly click on everything until a magical answer bag falls into their lap--in fact, users seem to have learned that asking terrible questions gets them that magical answer bag due to SO's timeless gamification dichotomy (or, more accurately, codependence.)  Anyway, I think it'd be beneficial for all to know about these easy-to-access-once-you-know-they-exist knowledge repositories from the beginning.

re: my quote above about tag wikis... Once I had read the thread that mentioned tag wikis, I went straight to the help center to find out what the heck they were.  Nothing.  I searched SO's meta.  Nothing.  I used google to search SO's meta: [finally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/329194).

## Conclusion

To be frank, it sucks that we have to have conversations like this one where we consider locking users out of this awesome platform.  My hope is that educating new users is placed on a pedestal in lieu of restrictions and limitations.

Comment: Incentivizing duplicate finding — and making it easier to find (or keep a record of) duplicates — would be a great help.

Comment: I love the suggestion of how to tell users why their email is blocked. A much more educational approach should be used for this, to make sure that we're helping new users get the most out of SO. For the rest I'll stick with my suggestion of copying credit card fraud solutions.

Comment: You'd have to start by removing the 3000 rep point requirement for flagging something as a duplicate, which IMO is about 2990 rep points higher than it should be.

Comment: @dgatwood afaik, anyone with 50 reputation may *flag* a question as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: I don't agree with the dupe finding. What SO needs is a traditional FAQ systems where all the good FAQs are listed at one page. A better system would be one where gold tag users could vote to nominate a question to become a FAQ/canonical duplicate. Then when searching for a canonical duplicate, you only need to check the posts listed as FAQ. With the current system, everyone who frequently close vote already have their own private collection of FAQs. It would be much better if there was an official one.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that offering better tools for managing duplicates will increase the consistency of choosing the best "canonical" duplicate possible and make it easier to engage with dupe-finding.  For FAQs, we already have tag wikis that (most?*) new users don't know about. However, my target is not our superusers who already seek out duplicates and have a healthy behavior in the system.  While we should look into getting them better tools, the goal here is getting education to the newer users to engage in these behaviors, too, so that the work isn't *always* offloaded onto our superstars.

Answer (score 12):

What about if instead of restricting user registrations, you treat questions by unproven users differently?

Put them in a separate bucket and treat them as 2nd class questions until one of the following happens :

- They get upvoted
- They get an answer that is upvoted (by someone other than the OP?)
- OP hits a specific rep milestone

These second class questions would get treated differently :

- Are ranked lower in Google Searches (can we do this?)
- Can be filtered by users who don't want to see them
- Are excluded from "hot" lists
- Possibly ranked lower on the Home page
- On track to be Roomba'd and deleted

Keep in mind this is only for questions posted by users who have not proven they can ask a decent question or that they understand the site. Once they get some rep, their questions would be treated the same as any other.

I've seen ideas like this in the past, and some of the concerns are

> Nobody will monitor the 2nd class questions

Now personally, I don't mind beginner, or even bad questions. I just like helping people, pointing them in the right direction or guiding them to ask better questions. Back when I was actively going for rep, these were some of the only questions I could answer because I either didn't know enough, or wasn't fast enough. I don't see this as being a problem.

> New questions need visibility

They'll still exist in the question lists for most users. Filtering them out will be an opt-in thing for users that care about this kind of thing. For most users who don't know/care, or those who like seeing all questions, or rep hunting, or who just like helping people, we'll still see them.

> It will be too easy to gain rep in low quality questions

Rep is just a measure of activity, not necessarily excellence. In my opinion, people who are active on this site helping others deserve rep. Those who stick around for any amount of time will learn the site rules and eventually grow to help more then they hurt, and potentially be the high-rep users of tomorrow. And if you're really that concerned, scale the rep games for 2nd class questions.

> We don't want to drive away "experts" by treating them as nooblords

If you can ask a decent question, it will usually get upvoted, especially if users are aware of how 2nd class questions work. There are many of us that just like to answer questions, and don't care how the site is run as long as it doesn't impact our ability to help people, and we will not be filtering out newbie questions. I'm sure we've all seen high rep users post answers to "bad" questions to prove that.

**TLDR**: Sometimes its much easier to allow everything and filter it, than it is to try to create restrictions and unnecessary hurdles that can drive away good users and content.

Comment: Honestly I kind of expect to get downvoted. I've posted [similar things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131835/158605) in the past, but my opinion really hasn't changed that much over the years. When dealing with the internet at large, I think it's easier and more accommodating to allow everything and let those who care filter, than it is to try to create restrictions and rules and hurdles for users to jump through. And if you want to stay the largest programming Q&A site online with an active community maintenance team, you can't be extremely restrictive of your userbase.

Comment: Yeah.  I think one big thing that's needed is a more nuanced approach, where new users' posts are tagged as newbie posts, but where old-timers can tag their own posts as newbie if they want to.  That way, people who have the patience to help newbies can do so (and newbies can help each other, of course), but they know what they're getting into before they click on the question.  :-)  Not even a filter, so much as just a visual hint.

Comment: This is the only answer that I can see that seems technical feasible, is practical, and isn't full of the typical "omg n00b questions are bad" premise that most of the other answers have.  A couple of points to make:  all questions are on track for the Roomba, given that they will be deleted if no one bothers looking at them, and a bit of caution in that this doesn't really do much to address issues in low-traffic tags which may not have the same quality problem as Android or PHP, but won't get as many eyes on it if a majority of their denizens opt-out.

Comment: It might be worth considering something like this in high traffic tags for a start - see what it does for PHP, Android and Java for example - and see if there is any marked improvements.  Actually, to that point, I don't think anyone here has defined in terms of numbers what an "improvement" would be...

Comment: I forgot to ask:  is this a visible thing or an invisible thing?  I could legitimately see backlash if it were plainly visible that this person's question is getting treated differently just because they're new here.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could avoid it being visible.  After all, the whole point is to have a way for users to be able to see only high-quality questions or everything according to their personal preference.  I mean I guess you could maybe try to do some sort of machine learning craziness to see what sorts of questions people answer, and go based on that, but IMO, it would be better if folks who are answering questions had that visible warning (e.g. a tag) to indicate that the question has a higher-than-average chance of being low quality before clicking on it.

Comment: @dgatwood:  I mean "visible" in the sense that the questions are put in a hidden second bucket, which is unbeknownst to the asker or answerer (unless they opt to see it).

Comment: I think it would be far worse to treat their questions as lower class without telling them that they're getting flagged as newbie questions.  Telling them ensures that if they don't get an answer, they understand why and don't just give up and leave.  It would also be good if the site treated newbie questions as normal questions if they don't get answered in a few days, thus ensuring that everybody sees them.  And the new users should be clearly told that this is happening, again so they don't give up and leave.  IMO, complete transparency is a virtue in this case.

Comment: I initially resisted this, because it creates "second class citizens" but now I am thinking an approach like this may ultimately be inevitable due to reasons of scale. As you point out, there are always folks willing to wade through the .. uh.. unfiltered.. queues out of the spirit of being helpful. If they could bounce and escalate the worthy questions, that might be a workable system. Still: see my other answer, here. Both approaches are worth following up on.

Comment: @JeffAtwood It's also an Opt-In feature to filter questions from unproven users, not an Opt-Out one. So only users who have taken the time to find a solution to "so many bad questions" will use it. I completely agree with your answer too though, that we need to improve guidance on the Ask page.

Comment: It could create churn from the "view unfiltered" mode and starve these questions from attention, effectively choking the site. Or it could naturally divide the userbase into "tiers". But then, we need to somehow encourage lower-tier users to push a worthy question upwards so that higher folks see it rather than answering it themselves to their (potentially insufficient) ability or just leaving it alone. So, an experiment is required indeed if anyone's thinking of moving this way.

Comment: Effectively, checks are already done in relevant review queues (but the review UI limits possible actions). The proposed additions effectively are: 1)make this happen in the normal UI 2)reduce visibility 3)auto-delete with prejudice.

Comment: Speaking of replacement of review: upvotes as a means for approval are a problem. They have another role: to give rep and rank a post among others. Saying that something merely "meets the site's standards" and that it's "particularly good/helpful to me" are two different things.

Answer (score 11):

> An obvious first step would be to prevent the use of throwaway email providers for new accounts. ... sharklasers.com, mailinator.com, yopmail.com, etc...

Absolutely! This is a great idea.

> IP-based restrictions are already used, but they're tricky to get right.

Already used? I am impressed. But yes, that only goes so far.

> Requiring some kind of two-factor authentication for new user signups has been suggested, but is this something that would work across the world? Would it be effective at slowing the creation of these new accounts? What form would this take?

An automated phone call or text message *might* be a good idea. The reason this would work is because you are associating a cost with duplication. Email accounts are free, but phone numbers - not so much.

However, I think that many folks out there may be uncomfortable providing their phone number from a privacy standpoint.

I think that easy registration is one of the great things about Stack Overflow, and we should hold on to it.

---

My initial experience on Stack Overflow when I first signed up in 2010:

1. **Recognition:** I recognized Stack Overflow by the distinctive voting icons to the left of the answers. I would regularly find Stack Overflow results on Google searches, and the top-voted/accepted answer was usually of great quality.
2. **Invitation:** The Ask Question button was very convenient. (I was not into asking questions on forums at the time.)
3. **Convenience:** It was so easy to ask a question. I didn't even have to create an account.
4. **Results:** Most importantly, the [answer was fast (3 minutes) and of great quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841095/install-and-update-android-app-from-my-own-website-and-not-market).

I think that the 'first question' experience is the most important for bringing on a potential new user.

I know that step 3 has changed a bit (account creation is required before filling out the question contents). Fortunately, most professionals have a Google account and can sign up with very few clicks (although they may not be keen on Google+, that's a different topic).

Comment: I think part of the appeal for me was that I could ask semi-anonymously without fear of my reputation being tarnished should I ask a question incorrectly or on a topic I *should know* as an industry professional. We should be careful to maintain that anonymity!

Comment: Making it super easy to ask a question is great when you have good questions to ask.  When you have bad questions to ask making it really easy is a problem.

Comment: not everyone has a mobile phone - so textmessages would not only be inconvenient but hinder people to register. The phone call is only slightly better. I wouldn't have signed in if these restrictions were in action. So I agree, this would be a bad idea.

Comment: verification texts/calls can add unexpected costs to both the user and to stack exchange. Not everyone has unlimited texts/minutes and there are places where they don't have unlimited minutes on landlines/cell phones. Also need to remember that care would need to be taken so that the numbers texted/called don't end up being numbers that charge when used.

Comment: @crush, Indeed, There is value to the anonymity of my account to this day.

Comment: Today, I wouldn't mind sharing my email or phone number because I know that Stack Exchange will not share it or publish it connected to my Stack Overflow User ID. (with the exception of the MD5 on Gravatar, but this is minor) However, in 2010, not yet trusting the system, I would have definitely held my phone number(s) tighter than email.

Comment: well I wouldn't buy a mobile phone extra for stackoverflow...But I wouldn't mind that my questions get reviewed like edits before they get opened - as long as I get the feedback I need.

Comment: We would have to also provide Voice Call, were we to use SMS.

Comment: I won't give out my phone number to a new service - wouldn't expect users to until SO has built some trust with them individually. If however SMS is ever used, there is also the issue of filtering phone numbers. For example, I use a VoIP phone service for everything (live in USA), but am unable to 2-factor auth with most Microsoft services because I'm not on a traditional carrier. Unsure if they whitelist or blacklist, but it's really annoying being locked out due to their (probably legitimate) screening practices.

Comment: @brichins This (and the feedback above by Rhayene) is the kind of thing I was looking for with this question. Requiring some form of two-factor authentication for new accounts is a topic that has come up a few times, and hearing the downsides of it is useful.

Comment: @BradLarson two factor authentication is ok as a one off, but to have to use it as a log in when you clear your cache can be a real hassle, particularly if you change your number and forget to update it while still being logged in. It can become a difficult process of being locked out of the account.

Comment: @Yvette, This discussion is about 2-factor for one-time registration.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I don't have a problem with that. But that's one opinion of many,

Comment: *"However, I think that many folks out there may be uncomfortable providing their phone number "* - come on... Dating sites and porn sites even ask for you credit card number... "If you want a Stack Overflow account, you should provide a valid phone number to prevent creation of duplicate accounts. Stack Exchange will never share your phone number with anyone" - Make that part of policy and roll it in.  2 step verification is very common nowadays. I enter a verification code every time I login from a different computer for security. Pretty sure I'm not the only one who does that.

Comment: ^... I don't think **credible** users will have a problem with having a one time mobile number verification for registration.

Comment: @TJ so everyone who don't has the money for or access to a mobile phone is not credible? There are families that only own one phone - so this would could exclude people. And I don't think having access to certain things makes people more or less credible.

Comment: @Rhayene First of all, children are not allowed to use Stack Overflow (I think the min age is 15 or 13 don't remember exactly) secondly, mobile phones are extremely cheap. Let's be realistic, anyone who has access to internet and does programming is very unlikely to not have a mobile phone.

Comment: @Rhayene *"There are families that only own one phone"* - So there are multiple programmers in that family, they have computer(s), internet... but... not even a second hand black and white mobile phone? Lol that's funny and completely not realistic. There are families that do not even have enough food. But I don't think they are staring at Stack Overflow starving.

Comment: @Rhayene  You said *"I won't buy"*. It is your decision.  By reading your comment above it's pretty clear you **can** buy a throw away mobile phone if you really want to. BTW you don't have to keep paying for a service provider, registration is a one time process like your one time investment computer. We are talking about eliminating/reducing people having duplicate sock puppet accounts.

Comment: *"this investment would be only for SO"* - we only need *credible* people who is willing to make such a tiny investment for a life time access to SO. Others are the type of people posting garbage right now/spammers/people cheating the system. Having such a restriction will force the puppeteers to buy that many throw away mobiles phone which is the most effective way to reduce the problem we have at present.

Comment: @TJ if a "pay money to create an account" policy is the new way... *sigh* I would have prefered that this "verification" gets you earlier out of a newbie safetybelt or something like that.

Comment: @Rhayene Nobody is talking about having to pay money. Majority has their own mobile phone. You are in an argument/an exceptional case. You can even borrow a non-programmer friend's phone to create an account. The point is, once you start posting garbage here and you get a question ban, you'll have to find another friend for another number. I think you're not getting the point/ have not experienced the low quality crap content problem in SO.

Comment: @TJ if people start to use other peoples phones the entire thing is useless. What prevents a sockpuppet to use the phone of another one.

Comment: @Rhayene *"useless"*? How many people are going to trust someone with their phone and phone number registered in their name? Right now creating sock puppet accounts is very easy. This will make it harder. That's all we need.

Comment: @TJ for me that feels like the "want to hit one black sheep, hit 10 white sheep in the process too" aproach

Comment: @Rhayene more like hit 999 black sheeps who is currenly making puppet accounts without getting up from the chair in few clicks, ignore a stubborn white sheep who can't make a little effort to find a mobile number and prove it's not a black sheep.

Comment: As I said above, we should also provide Voice Call option. This is precisely for folks who have no mobile phone, or do not have SMS services turned on.

Answer (score 6):

Anything that stops your question from being visible for a reasonable amount of time, such as vetting the question could end up frustrating the user with genuine intentions.

Ultimately, most people come to sites like this when researching questions they have. If they find an answer, they don't need to become a user and in most cases go on their merry way. It's probably more likely that genuine users come here to ask a question they can't find an answer for after a little bit of searching.

These types of users wouldn't mind answering a few more questions that act as an educational tool for both them as new users as well as to SO as a source of user info.

What I would suggest is that after constructing your question, when you click to submit it the user gets asked some questions to ensure they have followed basic question protocol, such as 'Have you searched SO for similar questions to yours?'. This would show perhaps the top 5 questions brought back according to the title. Other questions could be 'Does your title accurately summarise your problem?' and show a couple of examples of good and bad. Basically, add in a question for each of the key points in '[How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'. These would be simple 'Yes / No' answers (on ticking 'No' you go back to editing the question). It may also be a suitable place to gain further useful information about the user, but that would be for another discussion.

The aim of this process would have the following benefits:

- Educate the user in how to ask a good question.
- Not too much of a hurdle for the genuine user. After all, if you've gone to the trouble of writing your question you don't mind answering a few more quality control questions to get it on the site.
- Add more steps to the process to slow down malicious users.

After a certain threshold of questions asked combined with question score these quality control questions could be removed. This approach would have the benefit of being a 'softer' approach compared to perhaps applying a technical rule based strategy that may unfairly disadvantage some genuine users (phone verification etc).

Comment: I'm unconvinced that most new users actually do a search first.  In fact, I think the first step would be, when a new user submits a question. to perform a search on the subject and tags of the question and present the results.  Only after the user had a chance to peruse the results and indicate that none were useful would the new question actually be posted.

Comment: @WarrenDew - I'd disagree that not many users search first. Many just don't know enough about programming to know exactly what to search for. You don't know what you don't know as they say. In these cases people feel like the only way they will find an answer is to dump a load of code and say "Help! Please tell me what's wrong with it!". Whilst this is not constructive, educating them in how to structure their question will hopefully make it more likely they will get an answer.

Comment: I've seen many thousands of questions easily solved by just searching the question title.  A very large portion of the user base clearly is unwilling to so much as perform a web search before asking.

Comment: @Servy - then hopefully this approach will educate them. Ultimately if they keep asking bad questions and get down voted normal procedures kick in. However, if they simply wonder "Why was that down voted?" then this process will remind them what to do when they ask their next question. Whilst searching for the answer sounds like an obvious thing, when you're new you may think "This is a Q&A site. Why can't I just ask here?". If someone does that it doesn't mean they're not genuine or can't learn from their mistake.

Comment: I my experience the number of people willing to even *attempt* to improve is low single digit percent.  Most people don't even consider the possibility that they even did anything wrong, and just blame the site and/or the people who interacted with their question.

Comment: Yes! We need to teach them how to ask a good question *at the time they go to ask a new question*. That is the only time they will really care and read it, because they want answers and have already bothered to come that far. It doesn't even have to be a lengthy process, just something that says *"Wait! Before proceeding, read these quick rules about asking"*

Comment: Stack overflow already does a search for their title.  It's shown right below the title.  The problem is that if you don't know how to do what you're trying to do, you probably also don't know how to craft a good search or a good question title.  There's probably some sort of interesting keyword scanning that could be done on the post body to improve those hints, and if so, it would be nice if SO would do that.

Comment: @Servy - this may be true, but then this process will slow them down a little, and flag the areas they need to be aware of. Where I think it might also be useful is that if the process takes that little bit longer it will put some trolls / spammers off, or at least reduce the amount of rubbish they put on.

Comment: @Servy - this may be true, but then this process will slow them down a little, and flag the areas they need to be aware of. Where I think it might also be useful is that if the process takes that little bit longer it will put some trolls / spammers off, or at least reduce the amount of rubbish they put on.

Comment: Adding a 5 second timer to the ask question page isn't likely to significantly reduce the number of bad questions.

Comment: A variation of this would simply be to require visiting (and hopefully reading) each article in the [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section of the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) similar to what is required to earn the [Informed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge or was required to earn the now retired [Analytical](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical) badge. The pinned articles in this section are especially useful and I regularly link to them in comments to new user questions after making meaningful edits.

Comment: @Sevy - I concur regarding the observation that many new users appear to submit questions that could be easily answered by searching existing questions. SO encourages new users to search first before asking a question, but it certainly looks like many new users ignore this implied requirement. Requiring new users to have completed a few searches before they are allowed to ask a question is one way to encourage the desired behavior.

Answer (score 6):

**No** (mostly, anyways), because I believe there are better solutions. SO/SE is the most restrictive service I have ever used for new registrations. Many times before I reached 200 rep, I considered just giving up out of frustration because I couldn't do anything (all my friends had). I'd imagine the current restrictions already push a lot of quality answerers and askers away, which I'm assuming we want more of.

#### Restrict email providers?

Legitimate users who use a blacklisted provider will be inconvenienced. Illegitimate users will be mildly inconvenienced, and not stopped at all.

#### Force phone verification?

Anyone who doesn't have a cellphone plan is out (me). Many/most illegitimate users who are multiple offenders may be stopped, but at a huge cost IMO.

---

After dealing with the immensely annoying pre-200 rep life on SE, the fact it's even being talked about making that worse makes me feel like many here are out of touch with reality. Something I never imagined would be considered. I was honestly hoping for *less* restrictive registration so I could actually convince human beings to use this service.

**After reading some answers and comments I think the best ideas are:**

#### <s>Force questions below a certain rep to be user-moderated before being completely public</s>

I'm not savvy enough here to elaborate much further, but that doesn't seem terribly inconveniencing. As a safety mechanism, the question could go automatically public in 1 - 3 hours so people aren't stuck in long queues.

#### Tag questions posted by new users and badge them visually

**Credit: @dgatwood**

This way they're easy to avoid if you don't want to answer potentially obvious questions and to make questions asked by new users automatically get archived after a few weeks unless either the question gets upvoted by a non-new user or the new user gains enough rep, thus reducing clutter.

#### Educate harder

When I signed up with the app, I had no idea as to the level of quality expected in questions/answers. The kicker? Can't even delete my own posts. I'm obviously not alone on this.

The only reason I learned what level of quality is expected was reading the Meta SE sites. I think a reasonable solution would be to force people to do a tour. The tour doesn't have to be fancy but it should be mobile friendly and force input from the user. This would at least weed out most uncertainty that the user doesn't know any better.

Comment: "user-moderated before being completely public"—sounds like the [Triage queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)?

Comment: @DanGetz, perhaps but the triage queue (from my limited understanding having just heard about it now) seems to attempt to factor in quality. If many low-quality questions are getting public (hence this question), I'd say those measures are not effective enough. Unless I'm mistaken and it does factor in reputation effectively (but then why does this Q exist?). I believe education is the better solution anyways, it isn't easy to know right from wrong here as a new user.

Comment: @DanGetz: No, the triage queue doesn't do that at all.  It operates in parallel with the questions appearing publicly, which is a very different value proposition from adding a new phase to the question lifecycle before it becomes generally visible.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was going by the famous diagram that shows "full visibility" not happening until Triage is done. Thanks for helping to clarify.

Comment: @DanGetz: Ok, you might be right that visibility is already reduced.  The new proposal (especially if you look on the comments on this page's question) is to prevent answering until the question undergoes review, and that's something that the Triage queue doesn't do.  Sure, triage can result in closing and stop answers, but while the question is waiting for triage it is opened and can be answered.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happened at 200 rep? At 50 rep you can comment; what else did you need to make the site experience "bearable"?

Comment: @TZHX, at 200 rep you can comment / vote on any SE site instead of re-earning the privilege every single time.

Comment: The problem with delaying visibility until someone approves it is that I suspect most people won't bother doing this, and most of them will end up going public anyway.  I think it would be better to tag questions posted by new users and badge them visually so that they're easy to avoid if you don't want to answer potentially obvious questions, and to make questions asked by new users automatically get archived after a few weeks unless either the question gets upvoted by a non-new user or the new user gains enough rep, thus reducing clutter.

Comment: @dgatwood, I think that's a fantastic idea and I agree, much better. I'll update it to include it in my answer later!

Comment: Phone? What's that got to do with anything? Is there no way to use network card mac address or something more relevant instead?

Comment: @Lundin, perhaps you should begin why a network mac address is more relevant than a phone number. Also no, your mac address isn't usually public-facing. Your router's mac is though. Also macs are easily spoofed anyways.

Comment: @user161778 To begin with, the majority of the population in the world does not have a cell phone. SO is a global site, the rest of the world does not necessary look exactly like whatever western country you happen to live in. Demanding that people buy a phone in order to participate on SO is as irrelevant as demanding that they must own a car. You need a network card in order to use SO, though.

Comment: @Lundin, using a cell phone number is a common practice. Not only that, a common topic **on this question**. It doesn't become irrelevant because most people don't have access to it. Also I'm arguing *against* the use of cell phone numbers, which you seem to have missed. You also don't need your own network card to access SO (libraries, internet cafes, friends). By the same logic they're irrelevant because many people in developing countries don't have access to one.

Comment: *by on this question I mean including answers and comments. This is meta, my answer tried to take into account other responses.

Answer (score 6):

## Other Sites Have Similar Problems

Stack Exchange is a community of people looking for help with their problems. Why don't we ask other sites for help?
In fact, I'll even offer up a site that I know.

### Max Barry's [*NationStates*](http://www.nationstates.net/) and WA Multies

In NationStates, there is an organization called the "World Assembly" (used to be United Nations, until [the *Real* UN got mad](http://www.nationstates.net/page=news/2008/03/31/index.html)), with the following entries in the FAQ:

> #### I have more than one nation. Can they all join the WA?
>
> No. While you can have as many nations as you like, only one may be a World Assembly member at a time.
>
> #### What if I sneak them in?
>
> First, please don't. This is against the rules, and considered cheating. Sophisticated pattern-matching software constantly scans for suspicious behavior and will expel nations from the World Assembly that it determines are likely to be cheats (known as "WA multies"). Repeat or large-scale offenders are deleted.

I know from experience that they are **not** bluffing; the mentioned software is the product of *13 years of work* and is pretty reliable. There's even a similar motive for doing this: the requirement of "endorsements" from other WA members to submit proposals, become a WA Delegate, or gain Regional Influence faster.

So think about it: another website had a very similar problem, and they spent a decade making advanced software to fix it. ***How about we ask them for help?***

Comment: I think you're solving the wrong problem.  The problem isn't people creating multiple accounts, nor is the problem that some users ask low-quality questions.  The problem is that the low-quality questions are given the same visibility as high-quality questions.  In an ideal world, people who have no rep would see potentially low-quality questions at a higher mix-in rate than people who have high rep, or some such, thus ensuring that newbie programmers can help each other without clogging things up for everyone.

Comment: @dgatwood it's not the same but a closely related problem: sockpuppets were explicitly stated to be a part of the problem by the OP.

Comment: The thing is, there's no way to prevent sockpuppet accounts.  The best you can do is mitigate their impact with graph theory.  Treat it kind of like a web of trust, where upvoting by people with lots of rep is more valuable than upvoting by people with minimal rep, where clusters of people upvoting each other's posts are effectively treated as a single rep point instead of hundreds, etc.  Then, use that ranking to determine how prominently a question is shown and how many users see it, and use question aging so questions that haven't been answered eventually bubble up to a larger audience.

Comment: @dgatwood you're really missing the point. Offering up NS was more of an example; the real meaning of the post is "hey guys, our site is *built upon* asking questions. Why not *ask other sites* to solve our problem?"

Comment: I'm not convinced it will help, as any site's strategy for solving that problem is highly dependent upon recognizing fraudulent access patterns.  For that game, they likely look for patterns where two users consistently vote the same way, connect from the same IP, are never connected simultaneously, etc.  Some of those patterns might be relevant here, but they might not, because this site is accessed in fundamentally different ways.  For example, on Stack Overflow, a user might have one account on a mobile device and a different account on a laptop, and none of those rules would help at all.

Comment: That said, if the folks who designed that site are good at that sort of analysis, asking them to do similar analysis on Stack Overflow wouldn't be a bad idea (if they're willing or hirable).

Comment: @dgatwood using different accounts on different devices just has something inherently wrong about it.

Comment: (I made NationStates.) Our approach boils down to: (1) Have a bot compile a list of the most suspect accounts based on their behavior; (2) Have moderators regularly inspect this list, investigate cases, and provide feedback on false positives, which can fine-tune the bot. Over time, this results in a very effective bot, which can auto-eject many rulebreakers. There are always a few who keep coming back, but it eliminates the bulk of them.

Answer (score 6):

I too will present numbers without coming to any conclusions. The following is for `Python` and comes from a pool of roughly the last 72000 questions. The recent questions were not excluded (future Roomba from some). They were not excluded because they are likely well represented in the net votes part of the below sheet. The owner rep is frozen at the time of the question, so there is no tomfoolery there.

Note, the reason Python was chosen was simply due to my at the moment tag I am assisting others with for reporting purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The new users asking terrible questions isn't actually the problem. A question without any upvotes and answers will eventually get [roombad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Also, why would someone ask a question if they got no answers?

We shouldn't be more restrictive about new user registrations. Instead, we should **discourage people from answering bad questions**. This is the actual problem. I often see users with more than 20k reputation answering very low quality questions, instead of closevoting them. Many of these users have a gold tag badge and could dupehammer these questions (as most of them are duplicates).

I think that if a question gets closed and deleted because it's awful (for example when someone dumps a thousand lines of code and says "it's not working, help me pls"), **all users who answered that question should be punished**. I don't know what the punishment should be exactly, but it could be for example -20 reputation, and even a temporary answer ban if it happens nth time.

Also, we should make it easier to close questions asked by new users. Reducing the amount of close votes needed to close a question asked by a new user to 2 or 3 seems to be a good idea.

Comment: Punishing subject matter experts for trying to be helpful will only drive them away from the site, which is the problem we're trying to solve by reducing the incoming flow of bad questions. People asking bad questions will keep coming here as long as Stack Overflow sits atop Google search results. Removing reputation gained when a question is deleted, fine, but outright punishing people for trying to help is not something I can support.

Comment: This assumes a lot.  First - I do possess a Java dupehammer and do close where appropriate, but there are questions which don't *exactly* under the dupe and I don't normally close.  Also, a bad question - if defined by its total score - can still be skewed if you get a group of people to gang-downvote on a single answer.  I've personally edited questions with a score below -5 and had them turn around successfully; punishing the answerers of that question would've made no sense since the question could have been salvaged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578987/how-to-reverse-the-string-cae2w3a-and-calculate-the-sum-of-integers-into-the-s

Comment: @BradLarson The people answering these types of questions *aren't subject matter experts*.  The subject matter experts are the ones looking for the quality questions and running from these types of questions.  The people answering these questions are the people who aren't knowledgeable enough to answer the better questions that have experts answering them, or the people that care more about getting rep than helping people.  "outright punishing people for trying to help is not something I can support"  Regardless of their *intentions*, they're *causing harm*.

Comment: @BradLarson When you reward people for *attempting* to be helpful, even when they're actually *being harmful*, then they're going to continue causing that harm.  When your feedback reflects the value of their contribution, rather than what their intentions were, then you actually improve the quality of the site.  You are in effect valuing making *actively harmful users* feel good about being on the site *at the expense of the people actually providing valuable contributions*.

Comment: I partially  agree with you I have heard people say (write) that it's easier for them write a quick answer than to find a duplicate question. But instead of punishing people we should make it easier to close questions, find duplicats etc. (although, I can find duplicates pretty easily most of the time...)

Comment: @FelixKling Why *instead*? Why not work on both ends of the problem, making dupes easier to find *and* reducing rewards for careless answerers who don't try to find them?

Comment: Removing the reward, by taking back any rep from answers on a closed question, is different from punishing someone by fining then -20

Comment: @FelixKling - I wish more people had the ability you have to not only recognize the canonical post, but also to create them! Your canonical posts are the gold standard in my opinion. Would it be possible for you to create a canonical post here on meta with guidelines for how or when to create canonical posts on main?

Comment: @TravisJ: Such high praise! Thank you :) This sounds interesting, I will have to think about that and have a look at existing posts about that topic.

Comment: As I've said elsewhere, most people posting duplicate questions **do** search for answers.  They just don't understand how those answers **apply to their particular broken code**.  They have trouble taking a correct solution and combining it with their non-working solution.  Punishing people for trying to teach them what they specifically did wrong will just result in even more users blindly copying and pasting chunks of code from Stack Overflow without understanding it, which is one of the absolute worst things you can possibly encourage.

Comment: "The new users asking terrible questions isn't actually the problem" Oh but they are. The tiny amount of actual good content there is on the site, is drowning in a flood of sheer crap. The flood of crap causes experts to leave the site.

Comment: Reviewing unanswered questions posted by new users with a score of one (1) brings to me two thoughts: "good luck to you" and "next question".

Answer (score 2):

*Given that most of the answers are getting downvoted like crazy, I'll throw in an extra one :)*

The root problem here is bad questions, but unfortunately all the ideas we ever have either get shot down, or have already been implemented and aren't sufficient.

So we come to limiting new user accounts. My understanding of the question was that it was about people abusing accounts to get around bans. Answers seem to have wandered into limiting *all* new accounts, which could explain the downvotes.

So what we really want is a way of increasing friction for someone who is asking bad quality questions: the problem being that there is no easy way to differentiate an 'innocent' new user from a 'banned just now' new user.

I know hell bans have been suggested and downvoted before, but I wonder if some kind of 'time limited' hell ban might work? For example, following a mod banning a user for bad quality questions, their questions would sit in some kind of purgatory, then after a week they'd be notified.

Not perfect, but it could just add a bit more friction. To obfuscate further, the question could (for example) still be visible via direct url, or by looking up the user, but not figure in any default tabs?

Comment: It will add friction to users that get banned for the first time, but do nothing to stop organized groups avoiding bans.

Comment: @IanRingrose, do you have a reference for this 'organized criminal groups' thing?

Comment: most people call them voting rings, and some of the voting rings are getting very clever...

Comment: "*the problem being that there is no easy way to differentiate an 'innocent' new user from a 'banned just now' new user.*" - Effort. Make signing up harder and posting questions harder and the posting side ugly, and lazy "give me teh codez" people won't do it. "I didn't google because it was too hard" people won't do it. "I didn't try any debugging" people won't do it. Answering can remain pretty and easy, Searching too. But if you only want questions from people attacking hard questions with hard effort ... make it need hard effort to post. But ... that's unwelcoming and against SE principles

Comment: (i.e. hard effort to post will be 1000% of the effort a lazy person has put in overall on their problem, and very off-putting. It will be 1% of the effort a hard working person has put in and not be a big hurdle to the desire to get a good answer to their question. Similar to the idea of rubber-duck debugging, except enforced instead of self-enforced).

Comment: `hold-my-hand.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

By reading the question, it seems like your solutions are "if this then do this". I would expect you guys to have hidden reputation systems (on IP address, email, users, ...) that only administrators know the rule/numbers. A sort of "bad-user-reputation" system.

If the user was from a bad IP address, add +5 to "bad-user-reputation"
If 5 users were just created from a new email domain, add +5
If they didn't read the FAQ, add +2
If they came on the site from a Google search, add -2
...

If that user has a reputation of 20, then this is a user to watch.

You should even have a reputation system on IP address. If too many people ask bad questions from a specific IP address, then that IP address gets a bad reputation. It doesn't mean that someone posting from this IP address is 100% bad; it just mean that there is a x% change that the user is bad.

Comment: Wait wait wait. It is quite confusing if you don't emphasize "**bad**-user-reputation". (All the way while reading your answer, I was thinking - "What?")

Comment: That's been there since the dawn of time and is called a "dossier". And it's virtually equivalent to [another proposition](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324367/648265).

Answer (score 0):

What if the new user should be given three reputation points instead of one in the beginning?

If he asks a bad question the first time and get a minimum one downvote then his reputation will be 1 [3-2].

And to again ask a question he must have three reputation points.

This will solve two problems:

1. The new user can ask their problem if they made their Stack Overflow account for only asking a particular problem.
2. This will prevent the future terrible questions from the user with reputation 1.

They will have to earn at least two more reputation points to again ask a question by editing a post or answering a question.

Comment: If they accept an answer to their question, they earn 2 reputation.  If someone cruising by disagrees with their original question (even after they've improved themselves; suppose it's someone that downvotes the question because they felt like it), they're back down to 1.  I don't see this accomplishing much.

Comment: this can be changed to earning 1 reputation instead of 2 reputation only for first accepted answer.

Comment: i'm just saying that, this type of concept can be applied to solve this problem. not the exact thing what i told. i know there will be some factors that can affect this.

Comment: This is effectively what happens now. The question ban algorithm has been tightened up to the point that if a new user asks a single bad question that is downvoted enough, they are temporarily blocked from posting another until the original has been improved or they contribute in some other way. As a result, I'm seeing people creating new accounts for each question they want to ask in an attempt to evade this, something that would happen with your suggestion as well. Thus the core of my question about ways of preventing this kind of recidivism.

Comment: is it possible to give a flash alert on a mobile device by SO when signing up for providing unique code. i read above that providing sms code is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

## No

New users are not the problem; it's the quality of posts that needs addressing - from *both* "veterans" and "newbies".

While it does seem more frequent that new users are creating bad first posts, I see just as much guff from users who have accumulated a few upvotes over time.

My suggestion would be to **have a constant ban threat**.

Any time any user wishes to make a new post (question or answer), their latest `n` posts (3 for example) must have a non-negative sum. In the event that, this sum is negative, these posts must be edited to an acceptable quality before they are allowed to post again.

The aim would be to make users think of their recent contributions, while existing bans aim to stop repeat offenders.

This does still weigh more heavily on newer users since if they have less than `n` posts, then they are judged based on all of their existing posts.

---

I don't think we will ever find a way to stop all bad questions, but stopping those users that stay from repeat offending, (I hope) will make it a much more pleasant place for everyone.

Comment: Your system assumes that every down vote is cast fairly. It doesn't work that way. People are sloppy. They don't read the whole post before voting. They misunderstand the post. They misclick. They might think they know the topic better than the poster, while in reality they know far less. And so on. Add to that "revenge down votes", which is also somewhat common.

Comment: @Lundin - Not really (but thank you for the feedback!), whilst a single downvote can be done in error, I can't think of a single time when downvotes across multiple posts have been because of misunderstanding. Yes, targeted downvoting could affect this but then that would be reversed at the end of the day, and any logic introduced could easily avoid this (i.e checking if those dv's are from same user or introduce a threshold instead so if the sum is less than -n)

Answer (score -1):

Creating a new email account is possible on Yahoo Mail, in 30 seconds.

Use cell phone number verification instead of email. It's just as easy if not easier, and it's done on many sites today. Yes, you can download an app and get a random number to use, but this is arguably more difficult or time consuming than creating a new email account.

I've created new throwaway email accounts for new accounts on websites, but I've never gone through the trouble of getting a new cellphone number to verify a new account from.

Comment: With services like Google Voice it's nearly trivial to get a new SMS number as well these days.

Comment: *"Yes you can download an app and get a random number to use"* - what? How is he going to get access to the code sent to that number?

Comment: @TJ basically you download an app that assigns you a number and that app acts as an SMS receiver for that new number.

Comment: Hmm... that's cool. I wish it didn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

### tl;dr

- Make "Similar questions" search take the body of the question into account (keyword scanning).
- Flag newbie posts with an auto-tag that goes away when their rep exceeds a threshold.
- Ensure that newbie questions don't count towards that threshold (only answers).
- Archive newbie questions unless the questions get voted up or the user graduates.

### Background

When I joined Stack Overflow, IIRC, it was mostly to answer questions, and mainly because I had seen some awful Networking answers that were downright dangerous from a security perspective that needed to be corrected ASAP.  I think I've asked maybe a half dozen questions on the various Stack Exchange sites in total.

On the flip side, sometimes I have joined a Stack Exchange site specifically to ask a question.  I always have done at least some research before getting to that point, so they're never newbie questions.  And having to wait a week before posting would pretty much mean that I'd choose to ask in a less-than-ideal forum rather than wait the week.

With that said, I also recognize that I'm probably the exception.  Most new users are probably also new programmers, rather than folks who joined the site after programming since they were six or so.  That's no doubt why I see so many low-quality questions.  Most of these questions suggest that the people involved are just getting started and really don't know what they're doing yet.

**There is a definite benefit from helping newbie programmers move beyond their problems.**  Even though these newbie questions have a tendency to be specific to mistakes that they have made that nobody else would make, and thus are often useless to the community as a whole, learning from the answers to their questions will help ensure that their next questions are better quality.

### My Approach To Answering Questions

Some days, I'm in teacher mode, and I'm willing to patiently help anybody with anything.  On those days, I go out of my way to help people, sometimes even staring at really painfully bad code to try to figure out what they're doing wrong, and I usually give them a long list of tips for making their code better in addition to making it work.  That's my "teacher mode".

Other days, I get home after a long day of working (or teaching), and I just want to focus on helping people who are having problems that they **couldn't** solve by asking any random programmer with more than one year of experience.  On those days, having a Newbie tag that tells me "let somebody else who has more patience look at it first" would be a godsend.  If it doesn't get an accepted answer in a few days, I'll look at it on a day when I have more patience.  :-)

### Proposed Improvement

Based on that, what I would propose is the following:

1. Whenever somebody joins the site, they have a Newbie badge.  This means that they're new to the site, and that their questions should be treated as suspect.  This badge should go away when their rep exceeds a particular threshold.
2. Any question posted by anyone with a Newbie badge should be auto-tagged with a Newbie tag.  The auto-tagged Newbie tags should go away when the user exceeds the Newbie threshold.
3. Anybody with a Newbie badge can upvote or downvote content from people with Newbie tags, but it won't add to or subtract from the Newbie's reputation.
4. Upvotes on Newbie-tagged questions will not affect reputation at all.  So if you're a newbie, the only way to get rep is to **answer** questions, thus proving you actually know something beyond how to ask questions.
5. If a question is tagged "newbie", unless that question either gets untagged by the newbie gaining rep or gets modded up by someone who is not a newbie, the question should be archived a month after they get their first answer, or six months after posting, whichever is later.  Once archived, these questions will be visible to the people who asked the questions and to anyone who posted answers, but won't pollute search engine results.
6. There should be an "Include archived questions" checkbox to let you perform a search that includes newbie noise.
7. Newbie questions that have not been answered after a long period of time should "bubble up" so that they get higher visibility in various ordered rankings, under the assumption that the reason for the lack of an answer is probably that they're legitimately hard, and thus possibly not a true newbie question.

   If the lack of an answer turns out to be because the question was just too much work for the limited benefit, somebody will no doubt mod the question down and undo the bubbling.
8. After you fill out the body of a question, when you submit, the site should scan the body for interesting keywords and then use those to search for additional related questions.  It should then ask you to look at those questions to see if they're helpful, and should have disclosure triangles that show summaries of each question inline.  For new users, it might be worth requiring them to disclose all of them before submitting.

### Benefits Of This Approach

This approach has several key benefits:

- We'll be able to glance at the tags and immediately know that there's a high probability of a low-quality question.  If experts feel like helping out, they can do so, or they can save their energy for questions that are likely to be more interesting and challenging.
- Newbies can help each other out, and it won't change their newbie status.  That means there's no problem with leaving the low-quality content out there, segregated slightly by the presence of the tag, because it isn't going to result in ranking inflation for the users who post the low-quality content, confident that it will eventually get archived and hidden from view.
- It encourages newbies who aren't clueless to take the time to look around and try to help others, thus boosting their rep and making it more likely that their own questions will get answered by people who aren't complete newbies.
- Because it is a tag, any user who is posting a question on a subject where that person actually feels like a newbie can use it to make it clear to folks that the question might be a stupid question, and making it less likely that someone will ding them with a downvote.
- The quality of answers you get from search engines and the quality of questions will be on the whole much higher.

Comment: I remember a long time ago they had meta tags for sorting questions, and eventually decided to remove them. Personally, I would be a fan of bringing back meta tags to help sort questions, so like your idea :)

Comment: I see no benefit to having a question explicitly tagged.  It doesn't serve to categorize the problem set being posed.  Even if it's a system-imposed tag, the tag still needs meaning.

Comment: The meaning of the tag is that the question was posed by someone who is new to the site or who is new to a technology area.  You wouldn't search for the problem by that tag (well, teachers might), but rather, you would use it as an additional clue about whether the question was likely to be low quality.  Folks who are new to the site would be encouraged to answer other newbie questions to earn rep.  Folks who are more particular about how they spend their time would tend to ignore questions with that tag unless unanswered for a while, assuming that another newbie will answer it.

Comment: Seems analogous to the homework tag, and I would imagine that it shouldn't exist for the same reason.

Comment: No, it's kind of the opposite angle.  The homework tag was put on by other people to say that the question was low quality, and thus it was kind of like an authorized form of abuse.  This tag is put on automatically for all new users, and for other posts, should be added only by the original questioner.  In fact, that self-only requirement should be enforced to prevent precisely those problems.

Comment: Added a bit about the related idea of making the similar questions search consider the body of the question, and showing these results when you submit.

Comment: @dgatwood _"Folks who are new to the site would be encouraged to answer other newbie questions"_ - would start a vicious cycle, as newbies don't know how to answer, either.

Comment: The suggestions seem to have a rational seed in them... I only cannot understand one thing: why should questions _by newbies_ get this treatment? I don't see anything in the suggestions that is relevant to inexperience with the site. All it deals with instead is the quality of a question, so it rather seems that a poor-received question, regardless of the user, should get this treatment.

Comment: That's kind of the idea.  If you are just new to the site, but aren't a newbie at programming, after you answer a couple of questions, make useful comments, or ask questions that get modded up, your rep will climb beyond that minimal threshold and your questions won't be marked "newbie".  People who are still learning the basics of programming won't get that rep as easily, and thus will be flagged as newbies until they do.

Answer (score -3):

I can think of some changes which can reduce (in theory) the incoming flow of bad questions from new user accounts.

1. Make [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) obligatory

Let new users be **informed** why Stack Overflow is different from other sites before they begin post questions.

I think about it every time when see yet another "I need a free control with {list-of-features}" question (in [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) or [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) section). Tour explicitly states: "Don't ask about... product or service recommendations or comparisons"

---

2. Improve Tour

There are little details what is a good question.

Emphasize, that ...

- Code formatting is important;
- A question is not a list or requirements and Stack Overflow is not a coding service;
- MCVE is important;
- MCVE is not a wall of code;
- MCVE is not a screenshot of code in IDE
- MCVE is not a link to a GitHub repository or to an archive stored on Google.Drive;
- Phrases like "Give me codes", "It is urgent", "It has to work until tomorrow", "Upvote me" are not appropriate;
- CAPS ARE NOT APPROPRIATE;

---

3. Fix broken reputation points arithmetic

A quiz question:

"A new Stack Overflow user with one reputation point asks a bad question. An experienced user (3K+ reputation points) downvotes the question (-2) and votes to close. Another user downvotes (-2) the question. Someone posts an answer and makes a tactical upvote (+5). New user accepts the answer (+2). What is their total reputation?"

The answer is 8. I think the real reputation value has to be 1-2-2+5+2=4 and displayed value has to be `Max(real rep, 1)`. +8 award is unfair for a bad question with 2 downvotes.

---

4. Give more motivation for experienced users to close bad questions.

For example, introduce new badges for closing questions (similar to Review badges).

Bronze, Silver and Gold badges for a number of question closed as a duplicate

Bronze, Silver and Gold badges for a number of question closed as off-topic (off-site resource)

Bronze, Silver and Gold badges for a number of question closed as off-topic (debugging help)

Bronze, Silver and Gold badges for a number of question closed as too broad

etc. ...

Comment: I have seen plenty of the people with the informed badge just post garbage.  Hardly anyone reads what we give them.

Comment: None of those things will help.  First tour basically froze my laptop.  Bad, bad.  Second, people who ask bad questions usually don't ask them because they don't know how to write a question.  They ask them because they need help, and they don't know a better way to get that help, and don't even know what to ask half the time.  Reading a tour doc won't help with that.  Before they can ask good questions, they have to know what they don't know.

Comment: ...and badges for closing are explicitly destructive (except, arguably, as duplicates - [there have been a fairly well-founded proposition for it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265245/648265)).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, what is "destructive" when 5 users took appropriate actions (voted to close) about low-quality questions?

Comment: It makes the users biased towards closure. If a badge is to be awarded for close voting, it shall be awarded for any voting, both towards and against closure (and there already is such badge).

Answer (score -7):

There have been some [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)s over the years which have proposed [slowing down the question-creation process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253305/215552) for new users.

We could implement this idea of a "question wizard" in a way that, when you are a new user, it takes, say, 5 minutes to ask a question. Then, when you hit 50 reputation, a few of the steps are taken away, and it takes more like 2 minutes. Then, at 100 reputation to takes a minute, etc..

Obviously the rate at which the speedup occurs can easily be adjusted as the team tests the idea out.

This would encourage users to keep their accounts longer, since it takes soooooo loooooong to ask a questions as a new user. It would also have the byproduct of (theoretically) increasing first-question quality, as users would have to slow down a bit and really think about their question (well, really just wait impatiently while the timer ticks down, but one can hope...).

This, combined with the more aggressive rate-limiting mentioned in the comments, could make the number of new accounts created more manageable.

Comment: The wizard is yet one more thing for users to ignore.  There's no gain for quite a lot of work.

Comment: Well, the point is that they wouldn't be able to ignore it; they'd have to go through the process to ask a question, and it would be a timed process.

Comment: While the "question wizard" is a great idea (I have also thought of that too), I don't think this will solve the issue about new user registration specifically. You could still create 50 accounts, opened the wizard and leave it open (e.g. for 5 minutes, or I dunno, since the implementation is still unclear) until you wanted to post a new question.

Comment: So.... What set of rules should this wizard has? Look at some of the best questions we ever had here... They vary SO MUCH I can't think of a "cookie cutter approach" that would make sense in a wizard.... And if it's not a one size fits all, it'll be hell to implement. But maybe im missing something

Comment: I was specifically calling out the linked question and answers (like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/215552)), which were received well (at the time, which was more than a year ago, to be sure). Basically, getting more "in your face" with things like duplicate matching, asking for more information, etc.. I just wanted to get ideas flowing, as it seemed to be going all into comments, which are harder to vote on.

Comment: The problem isn't the speed, it's the lack of searching ahead of time.  What would really be beneficial would be for Stack Overflow's "Questions that already might have your answer" feature to take into account interesting keywords in the body of the question, not just the title.  For example, if I post a question "HTTPS requests not working" but mention "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)" in the body of the question, I'd like to see SO recognize that it's a dup of question 30720813 instead of giving a bunch of irrelevant suggestions caused by an imprecise title.

Answer (score -12):

We have a well performing Low Quality Posts queue, in which most of the posts in question are landing due to the automatic flagging or by user interaction.

Is it possible to hide the questions written by users lower than say 50 rep and flagged as low quality. The OP should get some kind of notification about the delay and hidden status. If the community decides that the flag is invalid, the post goes back into the open questions lists (maybe on top of like when a new comment arrives), otherwise it will be closed.

This won't make the registration and questioning process harder, but it would encourage the new users to write better questions.

---

I am not sure if it is a thing already or not, but such patterns like error error messages indicating a parse error in the title (or even in the body) should be marked as low quality or something. Most of these questions are now closed as off-topic anyways or left as unanswered with a few comments underneath.

Comment: ["We should not make the innocent suffer to prevent morons from trolling / spamming"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations#comment350846_324220)

Comment: LQP is only for answers, not questions.

Comment: @Gothdo This is why I have an and in the sentence. If the question is not flagged, it has a green light without any delay.

Comment: As a second thought, we do it now. If I am about to answer a question, but I want to clarify something before I post my answer and have no account, I can not comment. I am innocent, I suffer and I may not answer.

Comment: I like this idea, I am wondering if it's not easier to have posts hidden, requiring "reviews" instead of "flags" to make them visible, rather than then all visible until flagged. Either way it's more work, but then it will be a cleaner site.

Comment: Wow, -6 for this, +26 for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324233/3469391? Consistent as hell...

Answer (score -12):

I see that Stack Overflow users are eager to close/downvote questions. *(I mean instead of trying to understand the problem and help him improve the question quality they instead just see it's easier to just downvote/close the question)*

When you come to Stack Overflow, it's because you have tried all other possible ways to find an answer and you didn't. *(Down, I'm talking about these people who tried and didn't find answers.)*

So the real question is: **Should the Stack Overflow community allow people without enough study to ask questions?**

A lot of questions have been closed as duplicates or downvoted, because the users who asked them don't know programming very well. So, they have no way to see how easy their questions are (that's the common cause of downvoting).

For questions closed as duplicates, a lot of users don't see the duplicate questions beforehand, because they don't know how to search for them. Just for a second, imagine you are one of these users and see if you can find this question. So, yes, it means the same exact thing, but the user expressed it with common words instead of programming words.

---

I have a lot of downvoting, because you saw a lot of bad questions and thought I was not honest, but I didn't say that every downvote/close is not true, but I said I saw a lot of good questions downvoted because it's just look so easy.

For example, my [highest voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521853/read-600-000-input-from-console-in-less-than-2-seconds) have been closed as off-topic and had -3 voting till someone tried to understand my question then he found that I haven't make the question clear so users didn't understand my question so they just downvoted and voted to close the question. When you are not native English things just get messed up in your mind, and it is hard to express what you really mean and it needs a little patience from the reader. That's what a lot of Stack Overflow English native users don't understand.

Comment: I have never understood why anyone would ever complain about a dupe that's merely *closed* as such. If it's downvoted, maybe that's painful. But if it's a dupe and it's marked as such, where's the problem?

Comment: "*when you come to SO it because you have tried all other possible ways to find answer and you didn't*" - Really? I open the front page and there is this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37626559/478656 - does that look like they searched or read anything at all? Or this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37624933/478656 which is off-topic and means they didn't even find the right site to post on, or this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37626456/478656 or this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37626450/478656 or this no details of what they're doing - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37598803/478656

Comment: The problem is that most dupes are only dupes in the eyes of the person doing the duping, because they actually understand the problem, and because the original explains how to do the task correctly.  It isn't always obvious to newbies how to go from "here's my broken code and here's a working solution" to "here's my code, but working".  That's why IMO the site should allow people to answer the duplicate question anyway, but not count it towards rep, and then archive the question after a period of time if it doesn't get un-flagged as a dupe.

Comment: But yes, you're right that a lot of newbie questions really are clueless.  That's a good reason for some sort of tagging approach and a very slight bit of segregation for questions asked by people without any rep.  That way, newbies can continue to ask easy questions and get easy answers without it affecting their rep, but those questions can be archived so that their low quality doesn't clutter the normal searches with questions that are unlikely to answer anybody's question other than that of the original poster.

Comment: have anyone of you ever thought about the not native english ones that asks question in SO ?

Comment: @NathanTuggy becasue he didn't get his answer ! , he get something seem dup but it's not really

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler i didn't say all people do that , if he didn't search first he deserve down vote/close, i was talking about the people that "have tried all other possible ways to find answer and didn't find answer"

Comment: @robert: So, if it's *not* actually a dupe, it can be edited to clarify how it differs. If someone can't explain how their question is different, why should we assume it is? Askers feel as though they have the right to an open question with their own personal answer all customized to every last irrelevant detail of their code. But they don't. Most dupes really are dupes and should stay closed. And the rest… well, I've done more than my share of edits to help reopen questions or clean up questions asked by non-native speakers.

Comment: @dgatwood: As far as I can see, the ideas to use chat invites for <20 rep users to personalize solutions when necessary are a lot closer to feasibility than allowing no-rep answers on dupe questions.

Comment: Yes, in this case, it makes sense, but you'd have to convince people to move past their general reluctance to chat, borne out of newbies' overuse of chat because of SO telling them that there shouldn't be more than a couple of back-and-forth answers.  They don't realize that quite frequently, their questions are the same sort of questions that other newbies have.  Keeping that back-and-forth happen in public means that newbies will gain better understanding by reading the answer.  Hiding that information in chat means that it helps one person.  It's a delicate balance.

Comment: @NathanTuggy well i had question exactly like you said and got closed so make it very clear what differs between the two question but got only 3 reopen votes , it's very easy to close question but hard to reopen it

Comment: @robert It is actually very easy to have a question re-opened if there is reason for it. First of all, as soon as a post is flagged for re-opening, it _always_ ends up in a review queue, where 5 high rep users get to read the question and see if they agree that it should be re-opened. On top of that, if your question was closed as duplicate and you make a good case in comments stating why it isn't a dupe, any person with a "gold tag" in the subject, that comes across your comment may chose to instantly re-open the question, no voting needed.

Comment: it's not as you say , my other question take about 3 days closed after it was edited before 5 people vote to reopen it

Comment: the one edited it vote to reopen it and me and another 2 in the same day, 3 days for another vote

Comment: (Re: "When you are native English". Don't you mean "When you are **not** native English"?)

Answer (score -18):

**Some observations from not a new user, but a recently active user:**

- I never search on the Stack Overflow site itself. I always use
  Google. Since Stack Overflow questions (answers) usually feature
  prominently in the search results that's why I end up clicking on
  them.
- As a newbie [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) programmer, but experienced in other languages,
  what I really want is examples that I can extrapolate from. I can't
  find good ones, so I end up asking questions on Stack Exchange after checking the Python documentation, tutorial point and reviewing 10 hits on Google Search and usually not getting what I need/want.

**So I offer up these suggestions:**

1. Make it harder to find the site by banning Google from indexing the site if this is even possible.
2. Have a proper advanced search tailored to programming, so I can be sure my question hasn't been asked before. Google sucks as a search engine for specialized knowledge.
3. Apply [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) and machine learning algorithms to the vast trove of knowledge contained on this site to condense it into some sort of indexed structured form which I would have to prove in some way that I read in part before being able to ask a question related to a section in the knowledge base.
4. Make it crystal clear somehow (and I'm guilty of this) that questions without example code (maybe a code tag) will be deleted.
5. After asking a certain amount of questions require a user to answer a question before being able to ask any more questions. In other words, get you feet wet, learn your subject matter and be forced to give back for the knowledge you've gained. Perhaps start gently suggesting and get more aggressive as the cutoff approaches.

Comment: "*Make it harder to find the site by banning google from indexing the site if this is even possible.*" Absolutely not. One of the founding principles of the site is that it creates information that is Google-able. Also: "*Make it crystal clear somehow (and I'm guilty of this) that questions without example code (maybe a code tag) will be deleted.*" No. Many good questions are not about why a specific piece of code doesn't work.

Comment: "*Apply AI and machine learning algorithms to the vast trove of knowledge contained on this site to condense it into some sort of indexed structured form which I would have to prove in some way that I read in part*" - knock yourself out; [the entire site content is downloadable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) and/or [searchable online with custom SQL queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -22):

I think what makes this site so great is the very thing that is causing this "problem".  That is the ease of asking questions for a new user.  You can't take that away like so many have previously said.  And I think the bad questions just goes with the territory.  Which is why the voting system is so important.

What might be an appealing alternative is an elite section of Stackoverflow, where higher level, more difficult questions are the focus.  There would be rep requirements to ask or answer on these questions.

Another option, would be to allow users to set filters.  Then their account won't see questions of new or low-level accounts.  I myself, don't have issue with "noob" questions and am happy to help.  But avoiding obvious duplicates would be nice.

It would probably be easy enough to analyze for question duplicates using text similarity algorithms (http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Comment: Finding the dupes is probably the least of problems, we already have test system like this, finding hammers willing to review them is harder...

Comment: Haha, I just got -10 for suggesting such a thing. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324134/463304 While I thought it may make sense for the answerers to be able to decide on their own what they want to see. (tab option on home page) There is the risk of abandoning the 'all questions' tabs and thereby hurting quick response times for the 'good' new users we need to get.

Comment: I like how every answer is being down-voted.  Maybe its just the standard toxic people that exist everywhere on the internet causing said issues.

Comment: @Kevin what issues?  Every answer is being down-voted because meta users disagree with them.  It's a very difficult problem, and the downvoting just demonstrates that there is no good solution available, and the only choices are between differing levels of badness.

Comment: This is not a bad idea, except the general public will be seeing all the crap and there's plenty of people who visit the site without creating accounts to find answers and I think we need to take that into account also. Keeping the place clean for all.

Comment: Allowing users to filter out questions asked by low-rep users is almost the same as completely disallowing low-rep users from asking questions.

Comment: I disagree, I would not use the filter, but some would.

Comment: @Yvette, *"general public will be seeing all the crap"* In [my proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324134/463304), *everybody* would be able to see the new 'reputable' tab. The general public would be restricted from getting their questions listed there, but would not be restricted from seeing it or even answering.

Comment: @Gothdo, I echo Kevin's sentiment. The filter is a tool that the answerers can use to favor reputation users, over newcomers.  While were at it, we should also allow them to filter the exact opposite. (newcomers only)  Supposing we gave them these tools, you would get mixed use, and not complete abandonment of newcomers. However this would require some consensus (a new meta question) before it was implemented.

Comment: _"I think what makes this site so great is the very thing that is causing this "problem""_ - devil's advocate: you find this site great because you got your crappy questions answered. Other people didn't quite like your questions, but you didn't notice or didn't care.

Answer (score -25):

Why?

Why should anyone care if someone asks a bad question?

Why should anyone care if someone else decides to answer a "bad" question?

What is the harm that you are protecting against?

Personally, Stack Overflow has now become the **last** place I go to for R questions, because the R people are, frankly, rude and hostile to anyone who hasn't made R their life, and appear to have decided that such rif-raf shouldn't be posting R questions in "their" pond.

This question seems to come from that same source, that same aggression. Why are you so eager to drive people away?

Comment: Early in the site's life, if you googled a programming issue and got StackOverflow hits on the top page of results, you could be sure that visiting those would be useful.  Now you're much more likely to get SO in the top page of google hits, but those hits are far less likely to be worth reading :(

Comment: Bad questions hurt everyone, including the person asking it, by degrading the overall quality of results found during search.  Remember that 99% of the value of SO is provided to people reading the site and finding existing answers.  The ask-a-question-get-a-personalized-answer is not supposed to be the normal operating mode.

Comment: If you see someone being rude or hostile towards those asking questions, let moderators know about it. We expect people to be polite to others at all times. The hostility and rudeness you see can often be attributed to someone having lost their temper after seeing the 10th example of scanning in homework assignments that day, or other terrible questions. It's like an immune system overreacting to an invader and causing an allergy. By working to reduce the influx of the worst questions, my hope is that it will reduce this irritation among subject matter experts.

Comment: @brad You just have to remember that uses like these consider downvotes, clarifying comments, closure, or other polite and constructive means of working to improve a question "hostile".  Anything but an answer that can be copy-pasted and run is "rude".

Comment: @Servy down votes and\or closure on a perfectly reasonable question ARE hostile.  Assuming I'm an idiot and just want a copy & paste answer is also rude and hostile.  R requires a different mindset than normal programming languages. Lashing out at people for lacking that mindset is rude and hostile.

Comment: @BenVoigt My experience is different than yours.  The search hits I get to SO as much on point now as the've ever been

Comment: @GregDougherty: "*down votes and\or closure on a perfectly reasonable question ARE hostile.*" ... No. Downvotes are *never* supposed to be personal. Therefore, it is wrong of you to take them personally.

Comment: ...seems you also got some personal down votes here as well. With the down votes surpassing the comment counts, one would assume there are some that never gave reason for disagreement.

Comment: @NicolBolas it doesn't have to be personal to be hostile. The people who haunt "R" questions on SO are hostile to anyone who does not make R their primary language. So they lash out w/ down votes whenever such people post. Just like 18 people downvoted my post here, in hostility to my point of view.

Comment: @GregDougherty: Anyone who is downvoting on SO for reasons other than the quality of the post is misusing the site and should be considered abusive. However, downvoting an answer on Meta sites represents disagreement; it is neither abusive nor a priori hostile. That you interpret it as such is your personal choice, regardless of the intent of those who downvoted.

Comment: Why should you care if the neighbours dog always comes into your living room and takes a dump on the floor? You are not sitting on the floor, you are sitting on the sofa. You are not staring at the floor, you are staring at the TV. Just learn to ignore the smell and learn to walk around the piles. There should be unspoiled spots here and there. Don't be rude against the poor dog, what harm does it do? In fact, I have stopped taking my own dog for a walk in the neighbour's living room, because they get very hostile each time I do so and even try to drive me away! What's next, locking the doors?

Comment: @Lundin Really? You can't avoid the smell and bugs of a "bad" question?  Interesting. Almost as interesting as your belief that you own SO, and the rest of us are merely visiting your place.

Comment: @NicolBolas does "downvoting an answer on Meta sites" cost people reputation points? Yes? How does harming a person's reputation NOT count as a "hostile" act?

Comment: @GregDougherty: "*does "downvoting an answer on Meta sites" cost people reputation points?*" No, it does not. Only on Meta.StackExchange, which isn't a true meta-site.

Comment: @NicolBolas An example of what I'm talking about WRT the R people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620274/how-do-i-delete-rows-from-a-data-frame-when-the-df-only-has-one-column Did a search, got no hits. Made query my title, got a match. Did post with my title, linked to Q with answer. Got 5 downvotes, because apparently making it easier to find answers on SO is bad.

Comment: @BradLarson see above comment for the kind of hostility I'm talking about

Comment: @GregDougherty: "*because apparently making it easier to find answers on SO is bad.*" No, because doing the research and then posting a duplicate of the question you found is not a good thing. You posted a question which *other people* had to close as a duplicate, thus wasting their time.

Comment: Wrong @NicolBolas they did not have to close anything.  They chose to close it.  As I said, my queries weren't finding that answer, so someone with a similar query in the future will find an answer now, where they'd would not have in the past.

Comment: @GregDougherty: "*they did not have to close anything. They chose to close it.*" By the rules of this site, duplicate questions are not allowed. That's why we close them. That's why we have a specific close reason for them. Follow the rules of the site is not optional.

Comment: @NicolBolas so you're all just a bunch of robots, following the rules without any thought or judgment involved?

Answer (score -34):

If you restrict you will lose. Create another partition for 'off topic' questions that can receive the treatment they deserve. You are essentially treating a bad question like you would treat a homeless person.

Comment: With warm blanket and a cup of soup?

Comment: Analogy failure. Bad questions are not people, and I feel not the slightest shame in closing or deleting them if they're not going to help people.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan probably the best idea. embrace the fact a noobie is what a noobie does and help them. some people are vindictive in nature and feel pleasure from public shaming but we all deserve the chance to learn.

Comment: I was pointing out the failure of the analogy, actually. I don't treat homeless people badly, so that last sentence doesn't make any sense to me. This answer is also poor because of its tone and lack of any kind of positive suggestion, which is, I believe, what the OP was asking for.

Comment: This is why stack overflow is useless. You who have responded aren't even trying to improve my answer. Does it make you feel good that you can criticize and improve your reputation?

Comment: @NicholasKinney No one gets rep from Meta. Criticism is not pleasant, but it **is** useful (usually). Downvotes on Meta are often used as "I disagree", unlike the normal SO site. Last but not least, we all make mistakes. Actually making mistakes is the only thing i'll certainly do in the future.

Answer (score -35):

It's not obvious what fixes might work here without actually testing things.  Sometimes ideas sound good, but contain some only later obvious flaw that dooms them.  And online we see immense web business that initially must have seemed absurd, and were never expected to loom large or last longer than a fad usually would.

In which spirit, some unorthodox experimental notions:

How about an experimental **gutters** section, where first-timers can post, and vote *as much as they please* for their own posts, (but not for the posts of others); an added enhancement to prevent gaming would be to limit downvoting, maybe a new user could downvote their own post only *once*.  The theory to test would be that low-vote posts might be better quality.

There could be awards and badges, like "Million time voter", or "Stuffer" for those who qualify.

---

The opposite method would be an experimental section **hades** where users are permitted infinite downvotes of others posts.  (But only one upvote.)  Logically it's much the same as the **gutters**, but the psychology might work out differently.  Here the rate of retaliation might be the most useful metric.   Badges and awards might be named "Vendetta", "Joffrey", et al.

Comment: "*The theory to test would be that low-vote posts might be better quality.*", so, if they downvote their own post, it might have been a better quality? :)

Comment: This thread is so popular with critics that my post has gone down 10 votes in under one minute.

Comment: @AndrewT., maybe they shouldn't be allowed to downvote _at all_.

Answer (score -68):

What if there was a required payment of $1 to create an account, the payment having to be made from a credit/debit card in the name of the person creating the account?

As it is hard to gets an unlimited number of credit cards, that should slow down the creating of multiple account.

The money raised could be donated to a charity, with the user being able to choose the charity from a pre-approved list.

(Requiring a mobile phone number will exclude some disabled people, so must not be the **only** way to create an account.)

Comment: And what about all the current existing account holders? This is dangerous waters indeed.

Comment: If requiring a phone number of additional piece of information is considered a turn-off for privacy- then credit card info is a definite no-go for this community

Comment: Please note that SE allows registration for new users as young as 13 years old. I don't think they can have their own credit/debit card...

Comment: Turning of new users is not a great issue, we have more of them then we can cope with...

Comment: Eeeeeeh.    Just no? I wouldnt give my cc number to a site that asks it "just to create your account". I dunno for you, but i kinda value my information and i try to be selective where i put it.

Comment: And what about people who don't have(or can't get) a credit/debit card?

Comment: @JoeW, I got no ideal how common that, given that someone must at least have internet access to use stackoverflow.

Comment: Having internet access does not mean that they have access to a credit/debit card. For example someone in high school or college can get access to the internet but not have any form of credit or debit card and you can't count on others to provide it for them especially since you want it to be in the name of the person. Not to mention that there are people who just avoid them in general and if they have one they do not want to use them online with all the security breaches.

Comment: Have you considered that millions of SO users are in countries where debit/credit cards aren't too common? Have you considered that millions of SO users might not want to reveal their real name?

Comment: That looks a lot like Experts Exchange - and many contributors and answerers on EE walked away when they started to charge. Do you really want that to happen here ?

Comment: @JonasCz,  on Expert Exchange you have to paid to read an answer to an existing question.   No one is thinking about restricting read access.