# The Quality of C++ Questions

Tags: discussion, question-quality

There seem to be a number of users asking C++ questions without conducting proper research, as is apparent in the following question:
[Why is using std::string still needed after #include <string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432573/why-is-using-stdstring-still-needed-after-include-string)

I understand that the users asking question about C++ cannot be expected to understand the language to its fullest extent, although I wish they studied the features of C++ before asking questions that use them.

Not only is it counterproductive for the person asking the question, since they are asking them on a case-by-case basis, but it may help fewer people.

I was thinking of providing links to websites containing complete documentation on C++ when users ask a question with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, but what can be done?

Comment: _"I was thinking of providing links to websites containing complete documentation on C++"_ Well, these are in the tag info wiki.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Make it more direct, as in, display a link below the question box when [C++] is added to their question with a message like: "If you are new to C++, please read the tag wiki first", if they have a low reputation score.

Comment: Why does it have to be C++ questions? As far as I can tell, it's just questions in general.

Comment: If this question disturbs you, you don't want to see the recently other questions in php asking for *"pls give meh teh wordpress codez and tell me, how 2 install"*

Comment: Maybe it's because people are too lazy, or they lack the passion, as explained in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow?rq=1.

Comment: I take it you do not frequent the [tag:php] or [tag:javascript] tags…

Comment: @TinyGiant yes, this may be applicable to "questions in general".

Comment: @deceze no thanks, I'm fine thank you.

Comment: Count your blessings.

Comment: It's questions in general. If you frequent within a tag you'll see it _all_ the time. I just DV, flag and move on.

Comment: The main problem might be that low-quality questions often get an answer before they are closed, hence no deterring anyone of asking here without doing a thing on research.

Comment: @Adriaan indeed, seeing several 10k+ users answering a no-research, give-me-teh-codez questions with many known duplicates is very frustrating.

Comment: Welcome to every other tag in SO, where the thinking is "I found an error, let's not Google it, let's just dump it into SO for an answer!" I mean PHP has [about 6.5k questions asking about the same basic error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=expects+parameter+1+%5Bphp%5D)

Comment: I consider this question a compliment for the C++ tag. The question quality problem has been around for years in pretty much all tags and only now is there finally a complaint about the C++ tag itself.

Comment: I see this problem everywhere on SO. So many questions can simply be answered by "whatever tutorial/class your taking, actually follow the damn thing and it will teach you."

Comment: We have almost half a million questions in [tag:c++], a language defined by a 1400 page standard (+ some reference to the C standard, ok). If the question is answerable, on-topic and not about some niche library, it's probably a dupe.

Comment: @edition  As for me then I consider the referenced question as a good quality question on C++. I am sure that it is your question that is counterproductive.

Comment: Ideally we could close such questions as duplicates (as pointers, really) to relevant C++ Documentation examples/pages. When that feature will be added is anybody's guess, however...

Comment: At least, with more case-by-case questions, there is a higher chance candidates can use SO in the exam ;) https://twitter.com/yesthattom/status/689926927696564224

Comment: The linked question is a classic "I am coming from a system X to a system Y" question. Actually, it is not such an awful question if you interpret it broadly. I think it is a valid conceptual question. Say someone on the JavaScript tag asked "why doesn't Angular 2 follow the DRY principle?". Obviously completely different, because the answer involves interpreting someone else's design philosophy, but maybe the person asking the linked question doesn't understand that in C++ `#include <string>` and `std::string` are neither arbitrary nor redundant.

Answer (score 36):

> There seem to be a number of users asking C++ questions without conducting proper research, as is apparent in the following question
>
> I understand that the users asking question about C++ cannot be expected to understand the language to its fullest extent, although I wish they studied the features of C++ before asking questions that use them.

This is a general problem of all of SO. The quality requirement on questions on SO has been dropped significantly over the years. There used to be a requirement that people actually had basic understanding about the topic they ask about. This policy was removed many years ago, meaning that even complete beginner questions are considered on-topic. The result of this policy has given more site traffic at the cost of quality.

If you feel that the lack of research by the OP is significant, then that may merit a down vote of the question. That is, if they could find the information themselves by for example reading the first chapters of a beginner-level C++ book or just Google it.

---

The way to deal with frequently-asked beginner questions is to close them as duplicates, since beginner questions have almost always been asked many times before. For such FAQs there often exists a "canonical duplicate" which is the preferred one to use for closing purposes.

If you know that such a duplicate question exists and that it is of high quality, you can flag the post to prompt that it should get closed as duplicate. Higher rep users will be able to cast such close votes themselves without using flags. And users who have a "gold badge" for the tag (in this case C++) are considered to have lots of knowledge of the topic any may therefore close such questions instantly, without involving anyone else (aka "dupe hammer").

---

As for your specific case, I think it is a pretty reasonable question. I would imagine that it should be a common one. Though of course the root of the OP's confusion isn't related to the inclusion of string.h but about how to use the std namespace in general.

The normal thing to do here would be to find a canonical duplicate along the lines of "Why must we type `std::` in front of all standard library identifiers?". But it would seem that no such duplicate exists, or at least I can't find one. Bit surprising actually.

(I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035659/include-string-but-identifier-still-not-found?rq=1) but it wasn't particularly good - should perhaps even be closed as a duplicate to the post in your question.)

So the correct approach here is probably to leave the question be, there are no obvious problems with it and no canonical duplicates seem to exist.

---

> I was thinking of providing links to websites containing complete documentation on C++ when users ask a question with the c++ tag, but what can be done?

First of all, there exists extensive on-site resources for this already. There is the [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) and the [C++ Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/topics) project. (The latter is of mediocre quality and I wouldn't personally recommend using it for any purpose.)

You should never post answers that contain nothing more than a mere link to an external site. This is frowned upon since SO answers should contain content by themselves - SO is a knowledge base, not a collection of bookmarks. In addition, such links to external sites tend to go inactive over time, meaning that people coming across it in the future won't be able to find the information they are looking for.

Therefore, if you want to provide links to external sites, it is best to do this in the form of comments. Or alternatively, flesh out the answer with an explanation together with the link.

Comment: I'm down-voting because this post is dismissive of a very real problem.

Comment: *"But it would seem that no such duplicate exists, or at least I can't find one."* [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239882/what-is-the-need-to-specify-std-prefix). Found a better one for the specific question at hand though.

Comment: How can you say that the quality has dropped when in 2009 and 2010 questions popped up with 1 line of text? The community would then proceed to give a one-line answer because the question is so trivial and get 300+ upvotes. This is very very common. If you would ask such a question nowadays you would get downvoted into oblivion. ( and get comments like : read the docs, google, etc.) but no, in 09 it was all fine. SO needed the traffic back then.

Comment: @Mikhail What part of this answer is dismissive of a problem? It addresses each point adequately, in my opinion.

Comment: @TylerH I think the post is correct about the origin of the problem, and has some good discussion about the particular case that motivated OP. But I don't see a solution to the problem of low-quality posts. From what I understand, the proposal is that SO should carry on with no changes.

Comment: @Mikhail This is various user advise, not a proposal for how to fix the quality problems of SO (because that would derail the question with off-topic discussions). Such threads can be found for example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project).

Answer (score 0):

I started just a few days ago contributing to Stack Overflow and I also noticed the lack of quality in many questions, including C++ tagged ones.

I personally experienced the feel of proudness, when I helped someone who does not really understand what he or she is doing. And especially in the beginning, I also really wanted to get reputation points for answering questions even if it was a very bad question and should immediately be closed. Sometimes there even is kind of a race for the first answer, to get reputation.

Maybe the reputation system could be changed, so that you only get a very small amount of reputation if you answer a downvoted question. I do not know that much about the mechanics behind the reputation system, but maybe if you are not awarded for answering bad questions, fewer people will do it. And if that could be achieved also the number of bad question could decrease, because nobody is answering them anymore.

Comment: Re *"...kind of a race for the first answer"*: That goes by the name [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

Comment: Ignoring that vote counts are a coarse and not entirely reliable method for determining question quality, sometimes a poster edits a question into better shape _after_ receiving some downvotes. Should answerers then be penalized for answering the downvoted but now improved question? The original downvoters may never return to remove the downvotes, and often these questions receive few views after editing, especially in busy tags; the vote count may never be non-negative for some questions of reasonable quality.

Answer (score -1):

C++ is widely used in the academic environment, i think this is one of the main reasons for the discussion.

There is a substantial difference in questions asked by people who are in school (and have an academic work with no context to deliver), from people who are trying to learn something themselves (and who usually do not have the patience to wait for a response) and people who know the basics of what they are asking, but need a new approach to solving a real-life problem.

The first type asks questions here because it is easy and there are a large number of users to respond, and he wants a solution that fits exactly with what he needs to complete the work without having to think or format the answer.

The second type asks questions here generally when the answer is not found somewhere else or when the subject is poorly documented. Students who really want to learn are in this group, and is not the case of std::string/#include !

The third type has no choice but to interact with others for help. This group does not need a command or a hint of which library to use, they need a viewpoint based on a personal experience (which can eventually be a library or command).

Another point is the ranking system of stackoverflow, i started to use the tool a little time, answer questions, to learn English... and i'm being bombarded by points and gaining rankings etc... by God, someone can be addicted in this and all kinds of questions and answers can arise not to learn or help but to simply earn points.

Comment: If your logic is sound, Javascript questions must all be well-defined and researched since Javascript is rarely used in an academic environment. My experience on SO is somewhat contrary.

Answer (score -3):

I don't agree with this post. For me, there are posts with bad quality in all tags, for all subjects.

And, contrary to the original post or others answers, I think that [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) questions/answers have easily a lot of votes. The majority of audit posts that I see in review are C++ ones. On point that every time I see C++ question with some code, I'm 99% sure it's a review audit (example: yesterday I get four audits, and three were C++ ones - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70738147/10952503), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70806378/10952503), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70591571/10952503)).

Answer (score -24):

This solution isn't C++ specific, but I think commonly used languages, especially those that are popular in the academic setting simply need higher standards that might be dismissed for other languages.

We should actively reconsider positions on things like:

- Geographic regions that are frequent sources of low quality posts should be penalized by the same kind of flow filters I used on my websites to prevent spamming/DDoS attacks
- Increase the aggressiveness of existing quality filters. I suspect these tools have tunable parameters. For example, a grammar scores might have such a threshold.
- Minimal reputation requirements?

At the end of the day there are two kinds of tags, new tags and old tags. Stop pretend the two are the same. When a tag becomes old we need to change the rules.

It might be useful if certain rules could be decided by the community on a per-tag basis.

Comment: Excluding geographic regions is censorship. It's bad to exclude a whole region, simply because a few users don't know how SO works. e.g. you'd ignore posts from a university because the freshmen can't program and ask bad question; then you'd ignore the most brilliant minds on the planet as well, simply because they happen to be in the same place. Ridiculous idea that, don't implement this ever.

Comment: Penalties based on geographic regions is a truly awful idea, ugh. And as the the rest of your post, it's based on nothing more than your gut feeling. Come back when you have a shred of evidence that any of it is based on fact.

Comment: @DavidG Which things? Obviously a penalty based on geographic region would automatically adjust in a transparent way. I suspect areas with large student populations would be most affected, I deployed these kind of spam filters on the websites I used to run, and have never looked back.

Comment: For a start, new tags vs old tags. For the region penalties, why should a student be punished because some of her peers have posted bad questions? That is absolutely not the same thing as spam filters. So no, no and three times no to that idea!

Comment: @DavidG To get into my local pub I have to be over 21. There are many 19 year old that can be responsible adults, but yeah some people from that group ruined it. This is one way to solve problems, although certainly it isn't fair to individual actors. A more interesting question is if this will actually help.

Comment: And what does age restriction for alcohol have to do with programming? I know a few young teens who do it for fun and I highly encourage it.

Comment: @DavidG I take it as a microcosm of a rule that is unfair to many individuals but has an overall beneficial outcome for the group as a whole (less drunk driving deaths in the USA). That is why I'm "okay" with something that is *unfair* but might improve the quality of posts.

Comment: Stopping people drinking isn't unfair on anyone and even if it was, it's for the ultimate benefit of them. Banning people from SO however, is grossly unfair and doesn't help them at all.

Comment: @DavidG Its not an argument for banning people, I just want different rules to apply for categories of people (whomever they may be) that are serial offenders.

Comment: But those individuals are not all serial offenders. Anyway, where have I recently heard a similar idea about treating people from certain regions with "special" rules?

Comment: @DavidG I don't see how this relevant for advocating using more meta data to screen the quality of posts. Or treating certain tags differently. I don't agree with Trump on banning Muslims because Muslims aren't a problem.

Comment: Neither are those poor individuals you want to treat differently...

Comment: @DavidG I think SO has a lot of tools and metadata that they can use to more accurately predict and throttle poor quality posts. If the metadata says that people from college towns like Urbana-Champaign are a consistent problem then I don't feel too bad ratcheting up low-quality posts filters.

Comment: I'm happy to use metadata to throttle posts, but not when it comes at the expense of hurting people who have done nothing wrong.

Comment: "For example, a grammar scores might have such a threshold" Would this grammar error of yours be enough to prevent you from posting, or should such a filter be more stringent?

Comment: @TylerH I think so. Especially if this kind of error is found to be a characteristic of frequently closed posts.

Comment: So you're happy to punish non-native English speakers as well as geographically based users?

Comment: @DavidG I think it is possible to detect low quality posts in a more robust manner.

Comment: Quality concerns should focus on the content of the problematic post and not on who posted it. Ideally, scripts would recognize bad questions and prevent them from getting posted on the site. Or if the scripts can't be made smart enough, use user reviews. The key is to find (and potentially fix) bad questions _before_ they get posted on the site. Anyway, I think this discussion is better to have [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project). There's lots of good ideas there.